# How to exit from Python without traceback?

Tags: python, exit, traceback

I would like to know how to I exit from Python without having an traceback dump on the output.

I still want want to be able to return an error code but I do not want to display the traceback log.

I want to be able to exit using `exit(number)` without trace but in case of an Exception (not an exit) I want the trace.

Comment: sys.exit() stops execution without printing a backtrace, raising an Exception does... your question describes exactly what the default behavior is, so don't change anything.

Comment: @Luper It is very easy to check that sys.exit() throws SystemExit!

Comment: I said it doesn't print a traceback, not that it doesn't raise an exception.

Comment: I think that this really answers the question you asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173278/is-there-a-way-to-prevent-a-systemexit-exception-raised-from-sys-exit-from-bei

Comment: Is this question specifically for Jython 2.4 or something like that? Because for modern versions of Python (even in 2009, when that meant CPython 2.6 and 3.1, Jython 2.5, and IronPython 2.6), the question makes no sense, and the top answers are wrong.

Comment: @LuperRouch: No. sys.exit() stops execution by just raising an exception. Therefore this exception terminates the program - **with** printing a backtrace. So this is the cause of the problem, not the solution.

Comment: @abarnert: Is this really "the answer"? I'm not sure: As far as I could learn from stackoverflow in consequence to os._exit() no cleanup is performed. Instead the process is killed hard. The question is: How to terminate a Python process gracefully WITH cleanup but WITHOUT a stack trace printed.

Answer (score 323, accepted):

You are presumably encountering an exception and the program is exiting because of this (with a traceback).  The first thing to do therefore is to catch that exception, before exiting cleanly (maybe with a message, example given).

Try something like this in your `main` routine:

```
import sys, traceback

def main():
    try:
        do main program stuff here
        ....
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print "Shutdown requested...exiting"
    except Exception:
        traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stdout)
    sys.exit(0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: There should be something like "from sys import exit" in the beginning.

Comment: Hi Roberto: 

exit() is available without importing it, though you can also import it from sys.

Comment: Note that in older versions of Python (before 2.5) the 'exit' builtin was a simple non-callable string.

Comment: If sys.exit() is called in "main program stuff", the code above throws away the value passed to sys.exit. Notice that sys.exit raises SystemExit and the variable "e" will contain the exit code.

Comment: i would suggest printing in stderr sys.stderr.write(msg)

Comment: In Python 2.x you might want to change the `except Exception:` to a bare `except:` since it is possible for code to raise exceptions that do not inherit from the `Exception` base class.

Comment: I *strongly* suggest removing the lines from `except Exception:` to `sys.exit(0)`, inclusive. It is already the default behavior to print a traceback on all non-handled exceptions, and to exit after code ends, so why bother doing the same manually?

Comment: @jkp - Regarding your comment: `sys.exit()` should be used for programs. `exit()` is intended for interactive shells. See [The difference between exit() and sys.exit() in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501121/the-difference-between-exit-and-sys-exit-in-python).

Comment: @ MestreLion - Not necessarily: I'm processing thousands of files during a six-hour overnight run. If one of the files causes an exception, I want the trace so I can debug next day, but I want the processing to continue for the rest of the files.

Comment: @Pierre: But the way this is written, it won't do that—it will print the exception, then exit with no error code. That's almost the exact opposite of what you want.

Comment: As far as i can see this solution **still** gives traceback in case of failure, doesn't it? The OP wanted to exit **without traceback**.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question asked.

Answer (score 87):

Perhaps you're trying to catch all exceptions and this is catching the `SystemExit` exception raised by `sys.exit()`?

```
import sys

try:
    sys.exit(1) # Or something that calls sys.exit()
except SystemExit as e:
    sys.exit(e)
except:
    # Cleanup and reraise. This will print a backtrace.
    # (Insert your cleanup code here.)
    raise
```

In general, using `except:` without naming an exception is a bad idea. You'll catch all kinds of stuff you don't want to catch -- like `SystemExit` -- and it can also mask your own programming errors. My example above is silly, unless you're doing something in terms of cleanup. You could replace it with:

```
import sys
sys.exit(1) # Or something that calls sys.exit().
```

If you need to exit without raising `SystemExit`:

```
import os
os._exit(1)
```

I do this, in code that runs under unittest and calls `fork()`. Unittest gets when the forked process raises `SystemExit`. This is definitely a corner case!

Comment: -1: This code is silly: why catch `SystemExit` just to call `sys.exit(e)`?  Removing both lines has the *same* effect. Also, cleanup belongs to `finally:`, not `except Exception: ... raise`.

Comment: @MestreLion: You're free to downvote, but if you read my comment just above yours, that's only true for 2.5+. If you read all of my post, I explicitly said that the code is silly and suggested exactly what you said in your comment.

Comment: Sorry, you're right... I forgot there was a major re-structure of exceptions in Python 2.5. I tried to undo the downvote, but SO only allows me to do so if the answer is edited. So, since we are in 2012 and Python 2.4 is ancient history, why not edit it and show the correct (current) code upfront, leaving the pre-2.5 method as a footnote? It will improve the answer a lot and I'll be able to undo the downvote, and will gladly do so. Win-win for everyone :)

Comment: @MestreLion: I started editing as you suggested, but this answer really only makes sense in the context of the question and a 2.4 environment. The downvote doesn't upset me.

Answer (score 48):

```
import sys
sys.exit(1)
```

Answer (score 19):

The following code will not raise an exception and will exit without a traceback:

```
import os
os._exit(1)
```

[See this question and related answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173278/is-there-a-way-to-prevent-a-systemexit-exception-raised-from-sys-exit-from-bei) for more details. Surprised why all other answers are so overcomplicated.

This also will not do proper cleanup, like calling cleanup handlers, flushing stdio buffers, etc. (thanks to pabouk for pointing this out)

Comment: Not suitable for normal exits. This solution bypasses all the Python cleanup code!

Answer (score 10):

something like `import sys; sys.exit(0)` ?

Comment: @mestreLion Then why do I get 

  Dets 06 18:53:17 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "debug_new.py", line 4, in <module>
    import sys; sys.exit(0)
  SystemExit: 0
        at   org.python.core.PyException.fillInStackTrace(PyException.java:70)

in my console?

Comment: @Val: because you're not using a standard python console. Jython is not Python, and it looks like it (or at least its console) handles exceptions differently.

Comment: @Val See [*Why is sys.exit() causing a traceback?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48571212/3357935)

Answer (score 5):

It's much better practise to avoid using sys.exit() and instead raise/handle exceptions to allow the program to finish cleanly.  If you want to turn off traceback, simply use:

```
sys.trackbacklimit=0
```

You can set this at the top of your script to squash all traceback output, but I prefer to use it more sparingly, for example "known errors" where I want the output to be clean, e.g. in the file foo.py:

```
import sys
from subprocess import *

try:
  check_call([ 'uptime', '--help' ])
except CalledProcessError:
  sys.tracebacklimit=0
  print "Process failed"
  raise

print "This message should never follow an error."
```

If CalledProcessError is caught, the output will look like this:

```
[me@test01 dev]$ ./foo.py
usage: uptime [-V]
    -V    display version
Process failed
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['uptime', '--help']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

If any other error occurs, we still get the full traceback output.

Comment: For using `sys.trackbacklimit` in Python 3, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21556806/832230).

Comment: Please send error messages to `stderr`, not `stdout`. Use this instead: `print("Process failed", file=sys.stderr)`

Answer (score 3):

Use the built-in python function quit() and that's it.
No need to import any library.
I'm using python 3.4

Comment: Please do not use `quit()` or `exit()` in your code. These functions are intended only for the interactive Python. See [Python exit commands - why so many and when should each be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19747562/320437) You can use `sys.exit()` or `raise SystemExit` instead.

Answer (score 2):

I would do it this way:

```
import sys

def do_my_stuff():
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        do_my_stuff()
    except SystemExit, e:
        print(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import atexit
import inspect
import os
import signal
import sys


def sigint_handler(signal, frame):
    sys.stderr.write('\nInterrupted')
    cleanup(0)


def _cleanup(attr, method, args):
    code = 0
    if hasattr(attr, method):
        try:
            getattr(attr, method)(*args)
        except Exception as exc:
            sys.stderr.write(f"Error cleaning up attribute {repr(attr)}: {exc}")
            code = 1
    return code


def cleanup(code=0):
    for attr in globals().values():
        if not(inspect.isclass(attr) or inspect.isfunction(attr)):
            if not code:
                code |= _cleanup(attr, "__del__", ())
                code |= _cleanup(attr, "__exit__", (None, None, None))
    
    try:
        atexit._run_exitfuncs()
    except Exception as exc:
        sys.stderr.write(f"Error running exit event handlers: {exc}")
        code |= 1
    
    os._exit(code)


signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, sigint_handler)


# -- Maincode down here --

def main():
    pass

# -- Maincode Ends


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        sys.stderr.write('\nInterrupted')
        cleanup(0)
```

P.S.: The output msgs from the standerd error stream ISN'T A TRACEBACK, but it can be friendly to users

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

What about

```
import sys
....
....
....
sys.exit("I am getting the heck out of here!")
```

No traceback and somehow more explicit.

Answer (score -9):

```
# Pygame Example  

import pygame, sys  
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()  
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 300))  
pygame.display.set_caption('IBM Emulator')

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)  
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)

fontObj = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 32)  
textSurfaceObj = fontObj.render('IBM PC Emulator', True, GREEN,BLACK)  
textRectObj = textSurfaceObj.get_rect()  
textRectObj = (10, 10)

try:  
    while True: # main loop  
        DISPLAYSURF.fill(BLACK)  
        DISPLAYSURF.blit(textSurfaceObj, textRectObj)  
        for event in pygame.event.get():  
            if event.type == QUIT:  
                pygame.quit()  
                sys.exit()  
        pygame.display.update()  
except SystemExit:  
    pass
```

Comment: If you would comment the code, it would increase the quality of the answer.