# Exiting a python script cleanly

Tags: python, exit-code

I am trying to exit a python script without the annoying error message coming up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#27>", line 3, in <module>
    sys.exit()
SystemExit
```

I have tried quite a few things, but none have worked. Here's an example:

```
while True:
    print "hi", #this just tests to see if I have exited.
    try:
        sys.exit()
    except SystemExit:
        print "Exited"
```

NB: The solution doesn't have to be anywhere close to this code, that was just an example of something I have tried

Comment: What system are you running on?

Comment: Are you running the script through an IDE, such as IDLE?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187970/how-to-exit-from-python-without-traceback

Comment: @Joel, yes IDLE. Should that make a difference?

Comment: @Shurane Windows 7, python 2.7.2.

Comment: There's also `os._exit()` -- but that probably shouldn't be used just to get rid of "annoying traceback messages"

Comment: See Levon's answer. I am achieving similar results as him.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I run this in the Python console (under Windows or Linux) I don't get any sort of error message when I use `sys.exit(-1)`. However, iPython will give me

```
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: -1
```

I suspect you are seeing error messages because you are working in some sort of IDE, is that the case?

Comment: Yeah, it was the IDE. Thanks.