# Stopping the Program

Tags: python

I am creating a program that would be a lot simpler to write if I could just end the program if something happened. However, whenever I use sys.exit(), that gives an error message, and I want a way to exit that doesn't show a message or anything. I just want a clean exit. If you know of anything I can use for this, please tell me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look on this: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187970/how-to-exit-from-python-without-traceback) (look at `os._exit`)

Sys.exit(0) means 'All is good' but if you have an error you should still exit with 1.