# Print an error message without printing a traceback and close the program when a condition is not met

Tags: python, exception, error-handling, customization, traceback

I've seen similar questions to this one but none of them really address the trackback.
If I have a class like so

```
class Stop_if_no_then():
    def __init__(self, value one, operator, value_two, then, line_or_label, line_number):
        self._firstvalue = value_one
        self._secondvalue = value_two
        self._operator = operator
        self._gohere = line_or_label
        self._then = then
        self._line_number = line_number

    def execute(self, OtherClass):
        "code comparing the first two values and making changes etc"
```

What I want my execute method to be able to do is if self._then is not equal to the string "THEN" (in allcaps) then I want it to raise a custom error message and terminate the whole  program while also not showing a traceback.

If the error is encountered the only thing that should print out would look something like (I'm using 3 as an example, formatting is not a problem) this.

```
`Syntax Error (Line 3): No -THEN- present in the statement.`
```

I'm not very picky about it actually being an exception class object, so there's no issue in that aspect. Since I will be using this in a while loop, simple if, elif just repeats the message over and over (because obviously I am not closing the loop). I have seen sys.exit() but that also prints out a giant block of red text, unless I am not using it correctly. I don't want to catch the exception in my loop because there are other classes in the same module in which I need to implement something like this.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use a `try:` and then `except Exception as inst:`
What that will do is give you your error message in a variable named inst and you can print out the arguments on the error with `inst.args`. Try printing it out and seeing what happens, and is any item in `inst.args` is the one you are looking for.

EDIT Here is an example I tried with pythons IDLE:

```
>>> try:
    open("epik.sjj")
except Exception as inst:
    d = inst


>>> d
FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory')
>>> d.args
(2, 'No such file or directory')
>>> d.args[1]
'No such file or directory'
>>>
```

EDIT 2: as for closing the program you can always `raise` and error or you can use `sys.exit()`

Comment: What is the "2" in d.args and is the error message "No such file or directory' customizeable (if I created my own Exception class object)?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know what the 2 is but it's not important. I'm showing you how to find the error message yourself. And the "No such file or directory" is a string which you can put into a variable and then do what ever you want to with. `errorMessage = d.args[1]`

Comment: The actual error for that specific line of code is `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'epik.sjj'` so that's where to 2 came from. the `.args` is a tuple of all the parts of the error.

Comment: Why not just a simple `print('blah-blah-blah')` instead of `d = inst'?

Comment: Also if I do sys.exit() or raise an exception that gives me a traceback. Is there no way to get rid of the traceback? or make it not show up

Comment: the `d = inst` is just me showing how to capture an error into a variable, in this case named `d`. You can do what ever you want is that part of the code. My aim to show how you can get an error message as a string using `try` and `except` statements (which are used for catching errors.

Comment: @user2560035 I'm sorry, I assumed you new how error excpetions worked in python. I suggest you have a read up: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html. If you have any questions, feal free to ask me.

Comment: @The-IT The `2` first argument comes from the [`errno` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/errno.html) and is the value of `errno.ENOENT`. The second argument `'No such file or directory'` is the output of `os.strerror(errno.ENOENT)`.

Answer (score 75):

You can turn off the traceback by limiting its depth.

### Python 2.x

```
import sys
sys.tracebacklimit = 0
```

### Python 3.x

In Python 3.5.2 and 3.6.1, setting [`tracebacklimit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.tracebacklimit) to `0` does not seem to have the intended effect. This is a known [bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue12276). Note that `-1` doesn't work either. Setting it to `None` does however seem to work, at least for now.

In Python 3.6.2 and above you should set `tracebacklimit` to `0` or `-1`, as setting it to `None` does not disable the traceback output.

#### Python 3.6.1 and below results:

```
>>> import sys

>>> sys.tracebacklimit = 0
>>> raise Exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
Exception

>>> sys.tracebacklimit = -1
>>> raise Exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
Exception

>>> sys.tracebacklimit = None
>>> raise Exception
Exception
```

#### Python 3.6.2 and above results:

```
>>> import sys

>>> sys.tracebacklimit = 0
>>> raise Exception
Exception

>>> sys.tracebacklimit = -1
>>> raise Exception
Exception

>>> sys.tracebacklimit = None
>>> raise Exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
Exception
```

Nevertheless, for better or worse, if multiple exceptions are raised, they can all still be printed. For example:

```
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>
```

Comment: `sys.tracebacklimit = 0` now works fine with Python 3.7.
`sys.tracebacklimit = None` did not work in my case.

Comment: `>>> sys.tracebacklimit = 0 >>> raise TypeError('asdas')` Output: `TypeError: asdas`

Answer (score 37):

You can use `SystemExit` exception:

```
except Exception as err:
    raise SystemExit(err)
```

See [the documentation on `SystemExit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#SystemExit) for more details.

Comment: This doesn't tell you the type of exception

Comment: Didn't work in Python 3.10. Returned same exception as a raw error.

Answer (score 16):

The cleanest way that I know is to use `sys.excepthook`.

You implement a three argument function that accepts `type`, `value`, and `traceback` and does whatever you like (say, only prints the value) and assign that function to `sys.excepthook`.

Here is an example:

```
import sys

def excepthook(type, value, traceback):
    print(value)

sys.excepthook = excepthook

raise ValueError('hello')
```

This is available in both python 2 and python 3.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156936/discussion-between-egmusic-and-mark-veltzer).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157117/discussion-between-mark-veltzer-and-egmusic).

Comment: Would there be a way to print only the value in the console, but full traceback in a log at the same time?

Comment: Sure. You can use the traceback module and do what ever you want in the 'execepthook' function.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to get rid of any traceback for customs exceptions and have line number,
you can do this trick

## Python 3

```
import sys
import inspect

class NoTraceBackWithLineNumber(Exception):
    def __init__(self, msg):
        try:
            ln = sys.exc_info()[-1].tb_lineno
        except AttributeError:
            ln = inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_lineno
        self.args = "{0.__name__} (line {1}): {2}".format(type(self), ln, msg),
        sys.exit(self)

class MyNewError(NoTraceBackWithLineNumber):
    pass

raise MyNewError("Now TraceBack Is Gone")
```

Will give this output, and make the `raise` keyword useless

```
MyNewError (line 16): Now TraceBack Is Gone
```

Comment: You could also subclass `SystemExit`.

Answer (score 8):

"Exception chaining can be disabled by using `from None` " - [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#exception-chaining)

```py
>>> try:
...     open('database.sqlite')
... except IOError:
...     raise RuntimeError from None

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
```

Comment: This is what i need. SystemExit(err) cannot be avoided in try block. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In general, if you want to catch any exception except `SystemExit`, and exit with the exception's message without the traceback, define your `main` function as below:

```
>>> import sys

>>> def main():
...     try:
...         # Run your program from here.
...         raise RandomException  # For testing
...     except (Exception, KeyboardInterrupt) as exc:
...         sys.exit(exc)
... 
>>> main()
name 'RandomException' is not defined

$ echo $?
1
```

Note that in the case of multiple exceptions being raised, only one message is printed.

This answer is meant to improve upon the [one by The-IT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17785098/832230).

Answer (score 0):

Use the `traceback` module with `limit=0` (or any other number)

```
import traceback
try:
    1/0
except Exception as e:
    traceback.print_exception(e, limit=0)
```