# How do I do the exception without the traceback?

Tags: python, exception

I have the function which you can see in the picture. How do I only return the last line only, when the exception is raised, without the other lines: traceback.., file"" etc.

```
def division(k, m):
    try:
        k / m
    except TypeError:
        raise ValueError ('hey') from None
    return k/ m
```

[image: Only want to return the: ValueError:hey]

Comment: What do you want it to return instead when the error happens?

Comment: You're not returning the exception, it is being raised. It is the interpreter that does you the "favor" of printing the traceback when it encounters an uncaught exception. Maybe this may be of help to you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17784849/print-an-error-message-without-printing-a-traceback-and-close-the-program-when-a?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put

```
import sys
sys.tracebacklimit = 0
```

Somewhere in your code. It will apply to all of your exception tracebacks though. I personally can't think of why I would do it, but knock yourself out!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide the exception, use `pass` instead of raising another exception.

```
def division(k, m):
    try:
        return k/m
    except TypeError:
        pass
```

If the exception occurs, this will return `None` by default. You could replace `pass` with a different `return` statement that returns whatever you want to use instead.

You shouldn't do the division again outside the `try`, since that will just get the error that you wanted to hide again.