# Python Exception - preventing traceback from being displayed when exception is raised

Tags: python, exception, traceback

I have the following custom exception class I created:

```
class MyException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, message):
        self.message = message
        super().__init__(self.message)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"MyException error -> {self.message}"
```

My goal is to only show the exception message, not the full traceback.
For example:

```
try:
    int('a')
except ValueError:
    raise MyException("Incorrect value")
```

should output only `MyException: MyException error -> Incorrect value`

This result can be achieved with `sys.tracebacklimit = 0`, however, I want to apply this only to my custom exception class.
Moreover, I don't want to use print statements to output exception message.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) to me.  IMO the thing that is raising an exception shouldn't have any say in how that exception is presented to the user.  Instead it seems like the calling code should `except MyException` and handle it specially if necessary.

Comment: would this work for you?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41414413/13592469

Comment: @n4321d not exactly what I wanted at first, but it will do the job too. Thanks a lot!