# SQLAlchemy: Disable printing query inside exception's stacktrace

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm using an `insert` statement, which bulk-inserts a lot of records. Some exception happens along the way, but I cannot see its full stacktrace, because the query is extremely long and it clogs up the whole console in `PyCharm`. The statement is simple:

```
    async with session() as s:
        statement = (
            insert(chat)
            .values(chats)
            .on_conflict_do_nothing(
                index_elements=[chat.slug]
            )
        )
        await s.execute(statement)
        await s.commit()
```

The query will be parametric, so it contains a lot of this kind of code:

```
$82289::CHAR(5), $82290::VARCHAR(255)), ($82291::VARCHAR(100), $82292::CHAR(5), $82293::VARCHAR(255)), ($82294::VARCHAR(100), $82295::CHAR(5), $82296::VARCHAR(255)), ($82297::VARCHAR(100), $82298::CHAR(5), $82299::VARCHAR(255)), ($82300::VARCHAR(100), $82301::CHAR(5), $82302::VARCHAR(255)), ($82303::VARCHAR(100), $82304::CHAR(5), $82305::VARCHAR(255)), ($82306::VARCHAR(100), $82307::CHAR(5), $82308::VARCHAR(255)), ($82309::VARCHAR(100), $82310::CHAR(5), $82311::VARCHAR(255)), ($82312::VARCHAR(100), $82313::CHAR(5), $82314::VARCHAR(255)), ($82315::VARCHAR(100), $82316::CHAR(5), $82317::VARCHAR(255)), ($82318::VARCHAR(100), ...
```

Is there a way of getting rid of printing the **WHOLE ENTIRETY** of the query to the console? Maybe I there is a magic switch in the `sessionmaker` or `create_engine`?

If not, I just cannot understand, how people would log such exceptions and / or save them to a logging server for later...

Comment: As a quick fix to debug it can you just catch the exception and then print it somehow yourself using the traceback module or something to that affect?

Comment: @IanWilson thanks, that's what I ended up doing. But it doesn't actually solve the problem, it only bypasses it for the time being, lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've encountered the same problem myself. I couldn't find a built-in solution, but I think I found a relatively elegant one. The `sqlalchemy.exc` Exception objects all have an attribute `.statement` which contains the query. You can set it to be an empty string and raise the exception. In your case it would look like this:

```
async with session() as s:
    statement = (
        insert(chat)
        .values(chats)
        .on_conflict_do_nothing(
            index_elements=[chat.slug]
        )
    )
    try:
        await s.execute(statement)
    except Exception as err:
        err.statement = ""
        raise
    await s.commit()
```

As a result, you'll have the error and the traceback, and there will be no bulky query. If you don't want the traceback neither, then you can use `.args` attribute that contains just the error.

Some good tips on handling traceback in errors can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21556806/13337711)