# Python exit commands - why so many and when should each be used?

Tags: python

It seems that python supports many different commands to stop script execution.
The choices I've found are:  `quit()`, `exit()`, `sys.exit()`, `os._exit()`

Have I missed any?
What's the difference between them? When would you use each?

Comment: You've missed `os.abort()`

Answer (score 145, accepted):

The functions<sup>*</sup> `quit()`, `exit()`, and `sys.exit()` function in the same way: they raise the `SystemExit` exception.  So there is no real difference, except that `sys.exit()` is always available but `exit()` and `quit()` are only available if the `site` module is imported ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#constants-added-by-the-site-module)).

The `os._exit()` function is special, it exits immediately without calling any cleanup functions (it doesn't flush buffers, for example).  This is designed for highly specialized use cases... basically, only in the child after an `os.fork()` call.

### Conclusion

- Use `exit()` or `quit()` in the REPL.
- Use `sys.exit()` in scripts, or `raise SystemExit()` if you prefer.
- Use `os._exit()` for child processes to exit after a call to `os.fork()`.

All of these can be called without arguments, or you can specify the exit status, e.g., `exit(1)` or `raise SystemExit(1)` to exit with status 1. Note that portable programs are limited to exit status codes in the range 0-255, if you `raise SystemExit(256)` on many systems this will get truncated and your process will actually exit with status 0.

#### Footnotes

<sup>*</sup> Actually, `quit()` and `exit()` are callable instance objects, but I think it's okay to call them functions.

Answer (score 966):

Let me give some information on them:

1. [`quit()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/constants.html#quit) simply raises the [`SystemExit`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.SystemExit) exception.

   Furthermore, if you print it, it will give a message:

   ```
   >>> print (quit)
   Use quit() or Ctrl-Z plus Return to exit
   >>>
   ```

   This functionality was included to help people who do not know Python.  After all, one of the most likely things a newbie will try to exit Python is typing in `quit`.

   Nevertheless, `quit` should **not** be used in production code.  This is because it only works if the [`site`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/constants.html#constants-added-by-the-site-module) module is loaded.  Instead, this function should only be used in the interpreter.
2. [`exit()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/constants.html#exit) is an alias for `quit` (or vice-versa).  They exist together simply to make Python more user-friendly.

   Furthermore, it too gives a message when printed:

   ```
   >>> print (exit)
   Use exit() or Ctrl-Z plus Return to exit
   >>>
   ```

   However, like `quit`, `exit` is considered bad to use in production code and should be reserved for use in the interpreter.  This is because it too relies on the `site` module.
3. [`sys.exit()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exit) also raises the `SystemExit` exception.  This means that it is the same as `quit` and `exit` in that respect.

   Unlike those two however, `sys.exit` is considered good to use in production code.  This is because the [`sys`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html) module will always be there.
4. [`os._exit()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os._exit) exits the program **without calling cleanup handlers, flushing stdio buffers, etc**.  Thus, it is not a standard way to exit and should only be used in special cases.  The most common of these is in the child process(es) created by [`os.fork`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.fork).

   Note that, of the four methods given, only this one is unique in what it does.

Summed up, all four methods exit the program.  However, the first two are considered bad to use in production code and the last is a non-standard, dirty way that is only used in special scenarios.  So, if you want to exit a program normally, go with the third method: `sys.exit`.

---

Or, even better in my opinion, you can just do directly what `sys.exit` does behind the scenes and run:

```
raise SystemExit
```

This way, you do not need to import `sys` first.

However, this choice is simply one on style and is purely up to you.

Comment: But in ipython shell, `quit` and `exit` quit the shell while `sys.exit` doesn't.

Comment: `sys.exit()` is not a reliable way to close down. If it is called inside a thread, it will terminate only that thread unless it is in the main thread.  This can lead to a lot of cases where the program continues because the call was not in the main thread, especially as some interpreters will invisibly thread calls.

Comment: I vote for adding an `end` command which would `raise SystemExit`. Don't see why there can't be something simple like that, as in BASIC.

Comment: @BrianBurns: It's not worth adding dedicated syntax and reserving another keyword. This is similar to why `print` was changed from a statement to a function. It's easy to add syntax, but there's a complexity cost in doing so.

Comment: `raise SystemExit` is fantastic even if the sys library is not available in some restricted python environment

Comment: @iCodez - I've had a script running and it opens a pool to do some requests - and I have an `exit(0)` at the end (the built in) and also tried `sys.exit()` - although I noticed the processes remain open in `ps -x` - without any `exit()` the processes die off.

Comment: Is is just me, or would it be possible and even likely for some code to except all Exceptions and still run after SystemExit was raised? Even intermediate tutorials use this approache occasionally. Call an API, except and handle any Exception you can anticipate, except all Exceptions, log and do a default handling. (I checked the doc, so I know it's true). Is that generally bad practice or is it intended to overrule an exit filed by 3rd party code?

Comment: Do these exit all running python scripts or just the script one is in?  Also, if these commands are inside a method that is inside a module that is imported by my python script and called by that python script, will everything close?

Comment: @hajef Catching a SystemExit() is possible and intended. This is done by debuggers and some IDEs to allow the Python interpreter to not exit. I would recommend catching the most specific exceptions possible for the general case. I would assume a tutorial recommending catching all exceptions is likely assuming a SystemExit() won't occur.

Comment: **Exit(result)** makes better sense. It's unclear what code **raise SystemExit** returns. This can be very important if other scripts need to know if your program was successfully executed.

Comment: @hajef While it is possible (and intended) to catch a `SystemExit`, just saying `except Exception` won't do it, as `SystemExit` inherits from `BaseException` directly exactly for that purpose.

Answer (score 66):

## Different Means of Exiting

`os._exit()`:

- Exit the process without calling the cleanup handlers.

---

`exit(0)`:

- a clean exit without any errors / problems.

---

`exit(1)`:

- There was some issue / error / problem and that is why the program is exiting.

---

`sys.exit()`:

- When the system and python shuts down; it means less memory is being used after the program is run.

---

`quit()`:

- Closes the python file.

---

## Summary

Basically they all do the same thing, however, it also depends on what you are doing it for.

I don't think you left anything out and I would recommend getting used to `quit()` or `exit()`.

You would use `sys.exit()` and `os._exit()` mainly if you are using big files or are using python to control terminal.

Otherwise mainly use `exit()` or `quit()`.

Comment: "_Otherwise mainly use exit() or quit()._"  Even though the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#constants-added-by-the-site-module) states "They are useful for the interactive interpreter shell and **should not be used in programs**."?

Comment: There is also `exit("Here is why the program failed")`, which prints the error message and exits with return status `1`.

Comment: “`quit()`: Closes the python file.”  ???

Answer (score 46):

`sys.exit` is the canonical way to exit.

Internally `sys.exit` just raises `SystemExit`. However, calling `sys.exit`is more idiomatic than raising `SystemExit` directly.

`os.exit` is a low-level system call that exits directly without calling any cleanup handlers.

`quit` and `exit` exist only to provide an easy way out of the Python prompt. This is for new users or users who accidentally entered the Python prompt, and don't want to know the right syntax. They are likely to try typing `exit` or `quit`. While this will not exit the interpreter, it at least issues a message that tells them a way out:

```
>>> exit
Use exit() or Ctrl-D (i.e. EOF) to exit
>>> exit()
$
```

This is essentially just a hack that utilizes the fact that the interpreter prints the `__repr__` of any expression that you enter at the prompt.