# Why am I not reaping zombie processes? (CentOS Linux, python)

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am using a pool of processes. This logic seems to have been working until recently.

```
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes = 2*multiprocessing.cpu_count())
for p in processArgs:
    pool.apply_async(myFunc, p)

pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Now it seems when this is run, I end up with all child processes in a defunct state and the parent process appears not to have performed the `pool.join()` yet (based `a`) on the fact that the defunct processes are still there and `b`) on the fact that logic that occurs next appears not to have executed.

The defunct processes are zombies, right? This means they have died but haven't been reaped, correct?

Comment: [Does `ps -el` say they are zombies?](https://www.debian-administration.org/article/261/Finding_zombie_processes) Are you making sure that the pool has finished executing for all items?

Comment: It does show they are zombies (the Z is present).

Comment: Do I need to be making sure of exit before doing the pool.close() or pool.join()? To be honest, I copied this logic from an example and presumed the pool would've finished for all items before allowing the close.

Comment: @vmayer Just to clarify, are you saying that in your real code, whatever comes after `pool.join()` is never running?

Comment: @dano: yes, it seems so. I have logic that writes a file, and that file doesn't get written in any case.

Comment: @vmayer Have you confirmed that `pool.join()` itself is hanging? Can you created a minimal example that actually reproduces that behavior and edit it into your question?

Comment: Okay, it looks like what is likely happening is a call to sys.exit(1) from one of the processes. Does this make the process un-reapable?

Comment: Apparently, os._exit() is the right way to exit from a child process: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19747371/python-exit-commands-why-so-many-and-when-should-each-be-used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I don't understand it completely, the problem was that I was making a call to sys.exit() from one of my child processes. This is not the right way to exit from a child process, and os._exit() should be called instead:  stackoverflow.com/questions/19747371

sys.exit() does a bunch of cleanup first before exiting: perhaps it was stuck attempting to perform some of this cleanup, and the parent process was waiting to join it.

Feel free to provide additional explanation, and I can edit this answer.