# What is differences between site module and interpreter?

Tags: python

I am studying python, both 3. and 2.  I started a few days ago.
I want to know the differences between site module and interpreter.
I got this question from

[Python exit commands - why so many and when should each be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19747371/python-exit-commands-why-so-many-and-when-should-each-be-used)

Those explanations are very clear but it's still hard to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are stuck on understanding:

> "Nevertheless, quit should not be used in production code. This is
>   because it only works if the site module is loaded. Instead, this
>   function should only be used in the interpreter."

Basically, what that is saying is that `quit` is a part of a module loaded in the python interpreter. That module's name, is [site](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html).

Firstly, the **[python interpreter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_(computing))** is what you use to run python scripts or environments. It interprets python commands. For example, if you write `a = 1` in a script or python environment, the interpreter takes that command and executes it without compiling it. (If it was a language like c you would need to compile the script before you run it).

Secondly, a **[module](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_modules.htm)** is a pre-written file that can define functions, classes and variables. When you write `import numpy` into python, you are importing the module, numpy. Therefore when they say "this only works if the site module is loaded", that means that `import site` must be executed.

When you start a python interpreter (by typing `python` into your command shell), it automatically imports `site`, which has `sys`, `venv` and `main` etc. which are all required to run an active interpreter session.

Comment: thanks very much! I perfectly understand : ) have a nice day

Comment: @hwanseokjang Can you please select a correct answer to close the question. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding your question correctly,`site` is a module in Python. *A module is a file containing Python definitions and statements.* In order to use the functions (for ex: `exit()` or `quit()`, you need to import the `site` module as those respective functions are defined in there.

*The Python* `interpreter` *is the program that reads and executes Python code. This includes source code, pre-compiled code, scripts* - in this case you reference, you would need to import the `site` module into your current Python `interpreter` session, in order to use say `exit()` or `quit()` in that given session.

So, the process of this particular question would be:
* Activate the Python interpreter by typing into your respective terminal the version of Python you have installed on your computer, ex. `python3`.
* In the Python interpreter, type `import site`

Hope that helps Hwan.