# Find items in a text file that is a incantinated string of capitalized words that begin with a certain capital letter in python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to pull a string of input names that get saved to a text file.  I need to pull them by capital letter which is input.  I.E.  the saved text file contains names DanielDanClark,  and I need to pull the names that begin with D.  I am stuck at this part

```
for i in range(num):

    print("Name",i+1," >> Enter the name:")
    n=input("")
    names+=n          
file=open("names.txt","w")
file.write(names)
lookUp=input("Did you want to look up any names?(Y/N)")
x= ord(lookUp)
if x == 110 or x == 78:
    quit()
else:
    letter=input("Enter the first letter of the names you want to look up in uppercase:")
    file=open("names.txt","r")
    fileNames=[]
    file.list()
    for letter in file:
        fileNames.index(letter)
    fileNames.close()
```

I know that the last 4 lines are probably way wrong.  It is what I tried in my last failed attempt

Answer (score 1):

Lets break down your code block by block

```
num = 5
names = ""
for i in range(num)
    print("Name",i+1," >> Enter the name:")
    n=input("")
    names+=n
```

I took the liberty of giving `num` a value of `5`, and `names` a value of `""`, just so the code will run. This block has no problems. And will create a `string` called `names` with all the input taken. You might consider putting a delimiter in, which makes it more easier to read back your data. A suggestion would be to use `\n` which is a line break, so when you get to writing the file, you actually have one name on each line, example:

```
num = 5
names = ""
for i in range(num)
    print("Name",i+1," >> Enter the name:")
    n = input()
    names += n + "\n"
```

Now you are going to write the file:

```
file=open("names.txt","w")
file.write(names)
```

In this block you forget to close the file, and a better way is to fully specify the pathname of the file, example:

```
file = open(r"c:\somedir\somesubdir\names.txt","w")
file.write(names)
file.close()
```

or even better using `with`:

```
with open(r"c:\somedir\somesubdir\names.txt","w") as openfile:
    openfile.write(names)
```

The following block you are asking if the user want to lookup a name, and then exit:

```
lookUp=input("Did you want to look up any names?(Y/N)")
x= ord(lookUp)
if x == 110 or x == 78:
    quit()
```

First thing is that you are using `quit()` which should not be used in production code, see answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19747371/python-exit-commands-why-so-many-and-when-should-each-be-used) you really should use `sys.exit()` which means you need to `import` the `sys` module. You then proceed to get the numeric value of the answer being either `N` or `n` and you check this in a `if` statement. You do not have to do `ord()` you can use a string comparisson directly in your `if` statement. Example:

```
lookup = input("Did you want to look up any names?(Y/N)")
if lookup.lower() == "n":
    sys.exit()
```

Then you proceed to lookup the requested data, in the `else:` block of previous `if` statement:

```
else:
    letter=input("Enter the first letter of the names you want to look up in uppercase:")
    file=open("names.txt","r")
    fileNames=[]
    file.list()
    for letter in file:
        fileNames.index(letter)
    fileNames.close()
```

This is not really working properly either, so this is where the delimiter `\n` is coming in handy. When a text file is opened, you can use a `for line in file` block to enumerate through the file line by line, and with `\n` delimiter added in your first block, each line is a name. You also go wrong in the `for letter in file` block, it does not do what you think it should be doing. It actually returns each letter in the file, regardless of whay you type in the `input` earlier. Here is a working example:

```
letter = input("Enter the first letter of the names you want to look up in uppercase:")
result = []
with open(r"c:\somedir\somesubdir\names.txt", "r") as openfile:
    for line in openfile:  ## loop thru the file line by line
        line = line.strip('\n')  ## get rid of the delimiter
        if line[0].lower() == letter.lower():  ## compare the first (zero) character of the line 
            result.append(line)  ## append to result
print(result)  ## do something with the result
```

Putting it all together:

```
import sys

num = 5
names = ""
for i in range(num)
    print("Name",i+1," >> Enter the name:")
    n = input("")
    names += n + "\n"          

with open(r"c:\somedir\somesubdir\names.txt","w") as openfile:
    openfile.write(names)

lookup = input("Did you want to look up any names?(Y/N)")
if lookup.lower() == "n":
    sys.exit()

letter = input("Enter the first letter of the names you want to look up in uppercase:")
result = []
with open(r"c:\somedir\somesubdir\names.txt", "r") as openfile:
    for line in openfile:  
        line = line.strip('\n') 
        if line[0].lower() == letter.lower():  
            result.append(line) 
print(result)
```

One caveat I like to point out, when you create the file, you open the file in `w` mode, which will create a new file every time, therefore overwriting the a previous file. If you like to append to a file, you need to open it in `a` mode, which will append to an existing file, or create a new file when the file does not exist.

Comment: Thank you.  I knew I had to do this a different way.  I was trying to get it to work this way since I was told it would work.  I appreciate your reply