# How to stop python script

Tags: python

I made script for browser game. In this game, I am standing still and my script clicks on certain places bksononechno, but I need that if I clicked on the letter `k` This script would kill itself and not try to close the browser and its tab in the browser and something similar.

Sorry for mistakes.

Comment: `sys.exit(1)` in python program. `Ctrl+C` from running command line

Comment: You can take a look at [Python exit commands - why so many and when should each be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19747371/python-exit-commands-why-so-many-and-when-should-each-be-used). As mentioned, `sys.exit()` is the preferred one.

Answer (score 0):

You can add sys.exit(1) in the program itself and do Ctrl-C in the command line.