# How do you exit a python program without the error statement?

Tags: python, exit

How do you quit or halt a python program without the error messages showing?

I have tried quit(), exit(), systemexit(), raise SystemExit, and others but they all seem to raise an error message saying the program has been halted. How do I get rid of this?

Comment: use ```try...except... ```

Comment: What do you mean by error? The default message of python exit is this `Process finished with exit code 0`

Comment: build program in this way that it ends running without using any function.

Comment: add little more context to your question. I'm not clear reg your expectations.

Comment: when I use `sys.exit()` or `exit()` then it ends program without any error message in terminal on Linux. How do your run script ? Where do you run this script ?Maybe message is not from script but from program which runs script.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are trying too hard. Write your program using the regular boilerplate:

```
def main():
    # your real code goes here
    return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

and just return from function `main`. That will get you back to the `if`-clause, and execution will fall out the bottom of the program.

You can have as many `return` statements in `main()` as you like.

Comment: So `return` will stop the program

Comment: And does this mean that I can define other functions inside a different function?

Comment: @ChrisOliver `return` stops function `main()`, not program - but after main() there is no more code to run - so Python ends program.

Comment: So is there a way to `return` outside function

Comment: You *can* define one function inside another, but that is not regular Python style. They don't have to be inside `main`. Just write modular functions that you call from `main`, at the same level.

Comment: @ChrisOliver you can't use `return` outside function. You should rather use if/else to skip some code when you don't want to run it and then program will end in natural way.

Comment: *So is there a way to return outside function*. No, but this code is not doing that. Your main program (under the `if`) is calling `main()`, which is a function, and the code returns from that function. You can't put `return` in your main program but you can put it in any function that it calls.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to handle the exit in your python program.
For example:

```
def main():
    x = raw_input("Enter a value: ")
    if x == "a value":
        print("its alright")
    else:
        print("exit")
        exit(0)
```

Note: This works in python 2 because raw_input is included by default there but the concept is the same for both versions.

Output:

```
Enter a value: a
exit
```

Just out of curiousity: Why do you want to prevent the message? I prefer to see that my program has been closed because the user forced a system exit.

Comment: Please do not use `quit()` or `exit()` in your code. These functions are intended only for the interactive Python. See [Python exit commands - why so many and when should each be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19747562/320437)

Answer (score 1):

you can structure your program within a function then `return` when you wish to halt/end the program

ie

```
def foo():
    # your program here
    if we_want_to_halt:
        return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    foo()
```

Answer (score -1):

you can try the following code to terminate the program.

```
import sys
sys.exit()
```

Comment: When I try that this is what I get: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Chris\Desktop\Test.py", line 3, in <module>
    sys.exit()
SystemExit