# How to use exit() in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, exit

```py
import sys
import time
start = time.time()

key = input('Type your key:')
x = ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm',
     'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z',
     '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9')

for x1 in x:
    for x2 in x:
        for x3 in x:
            y = (x1+x2+x3)
            print (y) 
            if y == key:
                print('Founded')
                exit()
done = time.time()
elapsed = done - start
print(elapsed)
```

The code don't stop using the exit(), the program must finish all possibilities to stop.

Comment: I do not understand your question. Note, you shouldn't use the `exit` function outside of the repl

Comment: This code is not indented correctly. Please also explain why you believe `exit()` isn't stopping the program; what is the expected output vs. actual output?

Comment: The code is trying to figure out the key, it figures out but keep trying until all possibilities are tried. The exit() is to stop when the key is found

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python exit commands - why so many and when should each be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19747371/python-exit-commands-why-so-many-and-when-should-each-be-used)

Comment: Looks like you should have a function there that **returns** the value.

Comment: try `sys.exit()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put it inside of function and use return with "founded" flag.

There is no reason to use of `exit()` for such a trivial thing.

```
import sys
import time

def check():
    for x1 in x:
        for x2 in x:
            for x3 in x:
                y = (x1+x2+x3)
                print (y) 
                if y == key:
                    return True
    return False


start = time.time()

key = input('Type your key:')
x = ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm',
     'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z',
     '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9')

res = check()
if res:
    print("Found")

done = time.time()
elapsed = done - start
print(elapsed)
```