# How to fail maven build if python script get any error

Tags: java, python, maven-2, maven-3

I am using python script in maven project and want to fail build with proper error message if python script gets any error.

Is there something in plugin. from where we can fail build and display logging error if python gets error

this is my pom.xml

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>python</executable>
                        <workingDirectory>src/main/resources/</workingDirectory>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>my.py</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </configuration>
                    <id>python_build</id>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

and here is my python script my.py

```
import logging

name = "Amit"
age = 24
if name != "Amit":
    logging.error("name is not matching")

if age != 24:
    logging.error("age is not matching")
```

Comment: Exit with a Return code unequals zero.

Comment: can you explain it pls

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19747371/python-exit-commands-why-so-many-and-when-should-each-be-used

Comment: Is there something in plugin. from where we can fail build and display logging error

Comment: maven should fail if the python program terminates with an error code.

Comment: @Jens but i can't  see the error log in failed build

Comment: Do you see the log entry if you run the program on commandline?

Comment: @Jens yes I can see the log in my commandline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `exit` if you want raise an error:

```
import logging

name = "Amit"
age = 24
if name != "Amit":
    logging.error("name is not matching")
    exit(1)

if age != 24:
    logging.error("age is not matching")
    exit(1)
```

Comment: I can't see the error log which is generated by python