# Executing Python via Jupyter: Calling quit() and exit() raises NameError

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, nameerror

I'm executing a Python file `text.py` via Jupyter. I didn't get that error so far, but something changed, and now calling `quit()` or `exit()` raises a `NameError`. What causes this problem now?

**test.py**

```
def myFunc():
    print('yes')
    quit()

myFunc()
```

**test.ipynb**

```
#executes test.py
%run test.py
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are running python on two different python environment.

To check which env you are running you can add this two lines on top of your code:

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)

def myFunc():
    print('yes')
    quit()

myFunc()
```

running with:

```
python3 test.py
```

leads to this output

```
/usr/bin/python3
yes
```

instead from jupyter I obtain this:

```
/snap/jupyter/6/bin/python
yes

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/marco/Documents/gibberish/test.py in <module>
      6     quit()
      7 
----> 8 myFunc()
      9 
     10 

/home/marco/Documents/gibberish/test.py in myFunc()
      4 def myFunc():
      5     print('yes')
----> 6     quit()
      7 
      8 myFunc()

NameError: name 'quit' is not defined
```

Basically when you are running the code from jupyter you are loading a different set of builtin libraries

[Anyway quit should be used only from the interpreter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19747371/python-exit-commands-why-so-many-and-when-should-each-be-used)

Or you can simply use

```
sys.exit()
```

Which does the same thing :)

Comment: If I execute the file directly, `print(sys.executable)` returns the same as running via jupyter: `/Applications/anaconda3/bin/python`

Comment: If you add `sys.exit()` as replacement for `quit()`to your answer, I'm happy to accept it, since it solves my problem. Got that from your link ;)