# How can I close a Python program properly when in an IDE?

Tags: python, python-3.x

From what I understand, using sys.exit is not compatible with PyCharm and other IDEs, yet other exit methods that don't do garbage collection are not recommended. If I'm developing in PyCharm how can I properly shut down the program?

In the below example I am attempting to use a hot key to exit the program, yet the test statement is never reached. Is this an incorrect syntax or related to using the wrong exit command?

```
#Import modules
from tkinter import * #For images
from PIL import Image, ImageTk #For images
import os #For working directory
from pynput import keyboard #For hotkeys
#Set default directory
os.chdir('C:\\Users\\UserName\\Desktop\\Python\\SomeFolderName')

#Display Menu
root = Tk()
image = Image.open('menu.png')
display = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
root.overrideredirect(True) #Remove toolbar
label = Label(root, image=display)
label.pack()
root.mainloop()

#Functions
def ExitProgram():
print('test')
sys.exit(0)

#Define hotkeys
with keyboard.GlobalHotKeys({
'<ctrl>+w': ExitProgram,
'<ctrl>+0': ExitProgram}) as h:
h.join()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing past `root.mainloop()` will execute because it never returns.  Move the `with keyboard`... code before `root.mainloop()`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I've been trying to figure this out for hours.

Comment: Actually I did that and am getting "ExitProgram" not defined when the with keyboard code is above the function declarations.

Comment: Yes.  Move that before, too.  `root.mainloop()` should be the last line.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `quit()` function to exit the program. This is a built-in function from Python in order to exit the program.

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

This answer from a similar question might be a useful answer for you.

[Python exit commands - why so many and when should each be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19747371/python-exit-commands-why-so-many-and-when-should-each-be-used)

I actually use VS code and `sys.exit(0)` is fine, but can also use `quit()` which is also fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use `quit()` or `exit()` to terminate your program.
`quit()` and `exit()` are synonymous and do the exact same thing.

In addition to calling `sys.exit()`, using `quit()` does some other internal cleanup, such as closing input streams.

They are briefly discussed in the official documentation here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#quit