# When I close PyGame window the window closes but python becomes non responsive

Tags: python, pygame

I wrote a game with pygame. The game works fine but when I quit and close the window, while the window **does close** Python itself does not quit and instead shows (not responding) and I am forced to, well, force quit.

I start the code by importing several modules

```
import random, pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import*
```

There is only one place in the code that directly commands the program to shut down

```
def terminate():
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()
```

To quit the program always runs the `terminate()` function.

I tried adding `pygame.display.quit()` above `pygame.quit()` and substituting `raise SystemExit` for `sys.exit()`

What could cause python to close the window but not shut down itself?

Comment: Interesting question. I'm pretty sure the problem doesn't lie in the `quit()` or `exit()` calls, though -- could you share a more complete (runnable) example?

Answer (score 1):

I personnay don't imoprt sys to exit. It simply isn't effective for me to type `sys.exit()` and you can simply call `exit()` to exit the program.

So you can close the window like that:

```py
# main loop
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT: # if the user closes the window
            running = False


# after exiting mail loop
pygame.quit()
exit()
```

**[EDIT]** According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19747562#13633424), you should prefer using `quit()` instead of `exit()`:

> However, like `quit`, `exit` is considered bad to use in production code and should be reserved for use in the interpreter. This is because it too relies on the `site` module.

I don't get any problems now that I use `quit()`.