# How to Restart Azure iotedge service from inside a python module

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

I am working on a solution where I have to restart the azure edge runtime if one issue arrives inside the container.

Generally, the way to restart the azure  iotedge service is, to run the bellow command in  the host terminal

```
sudo ststemctl restart iotedge
```

how to achieve this inside of the container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that i have found for this solution is -
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/40541/rebooting-edge-device-remotely.html

Answer (score 0):

So you are running containers within containers? I have never tried this. While this seems possible, note that it requires granting docker extra privileges and may present security concerns.

> Generally, the way to restart the azure iotedge service is, to run the bellow command in the host terminal

You should be able to exec inside the container and do the same thing right?

Comment: No its not that, the solution i have found here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/40541/rebooting-edge-device-remotely.html

Answer (score 0):

I would let my module die using [exit()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19747371/python-exit-commands-why-so-many-and-when-should-each-be-used) so that iot edge runtime automatically restarts my module. I would also log the error before initiating exit().

I like to know if there is a reason for restarting whole edge runtime run just to recover from an issue in a container.