# when i convert pygame file to .exe file pyinstaller says can't open script

Tags: pygame, pyinstaller

I made a simple flappy bird game. I wanna convert it to *.exe* file, and I did it with pyinstaller but when I try to open the *.exe* file in the dist folder it says `can't run script`

I then copied my `assets` folder and pasted it into the `dist` folder, then too its not working.

**How do I make it work?**

Comment: seems like an issue with Your code. does it run fine normally? it could be to some modules not being initialized. What I suggest is that You one by one remove some parts of the code and each time create another `.exe` (so in total it will be quite a lot of files but You can just delete them after testing.) so continue removing blocks of code until the `.exe` file runs, then You will know where the issue is. basically create a [mre] but out of code that when compiled to `.exe` throws the error

Comment: Basically the first step is *"How can I see what is the error?"*. Then I think it will be an easy fix. The only problem is that you don't know what is the error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are converting a `.pyw` file, then PyInstaller will only show the game window when you will run it.

If you want to convert a `.py` file, it will also show the Command Prompt.

---

If you are getting an error in the form of a message box, that means that an error has stopped your code. Because you converted a `.pyw` file, the error will not be shown in the Command Prompt. A message box will appear instead.

To see what was the error in a more explicit way, you can:

#### 1. Convert your file from `.py` to `.exe` to see the error in the Command Prompt instead of in a message box.

Then, you can record your screen and see what was the error.

[image]

#### 2. Show the message box by yourself

Before converting your file, edit it like that:

```py
from tkinter.messagebox import showerror
try:

    # your ENTIRE code here

except Exception as error:
    showerror('Error detected', error)
```

This way the error will be shown in a Tkinter message box like that:

[image]

---

## Common errors:

- You forgot to put an image in the `.exe` directory
- `pygame.font.SysFont` does not work: use `pygame.font.Font` instead and use a `.ttf` file (more information [here](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.Font))
- `exit()` is not recognised, use `quit()` instead ([why `exit()` is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19747371#19747562))