# NSIS Error for python says: Failed to execute script

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, exe, nsis

So I am trying to create a python executable using NSIS and when I launch it, it gives me the following error:

[image]

These are my settings:
[image]

And this is my code:

```py
# import pygame library
import pygame
  
# initialise the pygame font
pygame.font.init()
  
# Total window
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 600))
  
# Title and Icon 
pygame.display.set_caption("SUDOKU SOLVER")
#a = pygame.image.load('icon.ico')
#pygame.display.set_icon(a)

x = 0
y = 0
dif = 500 / 9
val = 0
# Default Sudoku Board.
grid =[
        [7, 8, 0, 4, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0],
        [6, 0, 0, 0, 7, 5, 0, 0, 9],
        [0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 1, 0, 7, 8],
        [0, 0, 7, 0, 4, 0, 2, 6, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 5, 0, 9, 3, 0],
        [9, 0, 4, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 5],
        [0, 7, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2],
        [1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 7, 4, 0, 0],
        [0, 4, 9, 2, 0, 6, 0, 0, 7]
    ]
  
# Load test fonts for future use
font1 = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsans", 40)
font2 = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsans", 20)
def get_cord(pos):
    global x
    x = pos[0]//dif
    global y
    y = pos[1]//dif
  
# Highlight the cell selected
def draw_box():
    for i in range(2):
        pygame.draw.line(screen, (255, 0, 0), (x * dif-3, (y + i)*dif), (x * dif + dif + 3, (y + i)*dif), 7)
        pygame.draw.line(screen, (255, 0, 0), ( (x + i)* dif, y * dif ), ((x + i) * dif, y * dif + dif), 7)   
  
# Function to draw required lines for making Sudoku grid         
def draw():
    # Draw the lines
         
    for i in range (9):
        for j in range (9):
            if grid[i][j]!= 0:
  
                # Fill blue color in already numbered grid
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 153, 153), (i * dif, j * dif, dif + 1, dif + 1))
  
                # Fill gird with default numbers specified
                text1 = font1.render(str(grid[i][j]), 1, (0, 0, 0))
                screen.blit(text1, (i * dif + 15, j * dif + 15))
    # Draw lines horizontally and verticallyto form grid           
    for i in range(10):
        if i % 3 == 0 :
            thick = 7
        else:
            thick = 1
        pygame.draw.line(screen, (0, 0, 0), (0, i * dif), (500, i * dif), thick)
        pygame.draw.line(screen, (0, 0, 0), (i * dif, 0), (i * dif, 500), thick)      
  
# Fill value entered in cell      
def draw_val(val):
    text1 = font1.render(str(val), 1, (0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(text1, (x * dif + 15, y * dif + 15))    
  
# Raise error when wrong value entered
def raise_error1():
    text1 = font1.render("WRONG !!!", 1, (0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(text1, (20, 570))  
def raise_error2():
    text1 = font1.render("Wrong !!! Not a valid Key", 1, (0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(text1, (20, 570))  
  
# Check if the value entered in board is valid
def valid(m, i, j, val):
    for it in range(9):
        if m[i][it]== val:
            return False
        if m[it][j]== val:
            return False
    it = i//3
    jt = j//3
    for i in range(it * 3, it * 3 + 3):
        for j in range (jt * 3, jt * 3 + 3):
            if m[i][j]== val:
                return False
    return True
  
# Solves the sudoku board using Backtracking Algorithm
def solve(grid, i, j):
      
    while grid[i][j]!= 0:
        if i<8:
            i+= 1
        elif i == 8 and j<8:
            i = 0
            j+= 1
        elif i == 8 and j == 8:
            return True
    pygame.event.pump()    
    for it in range(1, 10):
        if valid(grid, i, j, it)== True:
            grid[i][j]= it
            global x, y
            x = i
            y = j
            # white color background\
            screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
            draw()
            draw_box()
            pygame.display.update()
            pygame.time.delay(20)
            if solve(grid, i, j)== 1:
                return True
            else:
                grid[i][j]= 0
            # white color background\
            screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
          
            draw()
            draw_box()
            pygame.display.update()
            pygame.time.delay(50)    
    return False  
  
# Display instruction for the game
def instruction():
    text1 = font2.render("PRESS D TO RESET TO DEFAULT / R TO EMPTY", 1, (0, 0, 0))
    text2 = font2.render("ENTER VALUES AND PRESS ENTER TO VISUALIZE", 1, (0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(text1, (20, 520))        
    screen.blit(text2, (20, 540))
  
# Display options when solved
def result():
    text1 = font1.render("FINISHED PRESS R or D", 1, (0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(text1, (20, 570))    
run = True
flag1 = 0
flag2 = 0
rs = 0
error = 0
# The loop thats keep the window running
while run:
      
    # White color background
    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
    # Loop through the events stored in event.get()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # Quit the game window
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False  
        # Get the mouse postion to insert number    
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            flag1 = 1
            pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            get_cord(pos)
        # Get the number to be inserted if key pressed    
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x-= 1
                flag1 = 1
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x+= 1
                flag1 = 1
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                y-= 1
                flag1 = 1
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                y+= 1
                flag1 = 1    
            if event.key == pygame.K_1:
                val = 1
            if event.key == pygame.K_2:
                val = 2    
            if event.key == pygame.K_3:
                val = 3
            if event.key == pygame.K_4:
                val = 4
            if event.key == pygame.K_5:
                val = 5
            if event.key == pygame.K_6:
                val = 6 
            if event.key == pygame.K_7:
                val = 7
            if event.key == pygame.K_8:
                val = 8
            if event.key == pygame.K_9:
                val = 9  
            if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                flag2 = 1   
            # If R pressed clear the sudoku board
            if event.key == pygame.K_r:
                rs = 0
                error = 0
                flag2 = 0
                grid =[
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
                ]
            # If D is pressed reset the board to default 
            if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                rs = 0
                error = 0
                flag2 = 0
                grid =[
                    [7, 8, 0, 4, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0],
                    [6, 0, 0, 0, 7, 5, 0, 0, 9],
                    [0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 1, 0, 7, 8],
                    [0, 0, 7, 0, 4, 0, 2, 6, 0],
                    [0, 0, 1, 0, 5, 0, 9, 3, 0],
                    [9, 0, 4, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 5],
                    [0, 7, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2],
                    [1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 7, 4, 0, 0],
                    [0, 4, 9, 2, 0, 6, 0, 0, 7]
                ]
    if flag2 == 1:
        if solve(grid, 0, 0)== False:
            error = 1
        else:
            rs = 1
        flag2 = 0    
    if val != 0:            
        draw_val(val)
        # print(x)
        # print(y)
        if valid(grid, int(x), int(y), val)== True:
            grid[int(x)][int(y)]= val
            flag1 = 0
        else:
            grid[int(x)][int(y)]= 0
            raise_error2()   
        val = 0    
        
    if error == 1:
        raise_error1()  
    if rs == 1:
        result()        
    draw()  
    if flag1 == 1:
        draw_box()       
    instruction()    
  
    # Update window
    pygame.display.update()  
  
# Quit pygame window    
pygame.quit()
```

This is how it is supposed to work:
[image]

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pygame.font.SysFont` does not work with `.exe` files created with PyInstaller. Use `pygame.font.Font` instead.

In the case of *Comic Sans MS*, you can download it [**here**](https://www.wfonts.com/font/comic-sans-ms). Then just copy one of the `.ttf` files in the same directory as the `.exe` file and use a code like that:

```
font1 = pygame.font.Font('ComicSansMS3.ttf', 40)
```

---

Anyways, if you want to verify what the error is, display it by yourself; before converting your file, edit it like that:

```py
from tkinter.messagebox import showerror
try:
    # your entire code here
except Exception as error:
    showerror('Error detected', error)
```

This way the error will be shown in the form of a message box like that:

[image]

---

More information about errors [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67497238#67534869).