# why does quit() not work on Python Embeddable for Windows?

Tags: python, windows

Normally when one want to exit an interactive session in Python, one can use exit() or quit(), but that does not work on  Windows embeddable Python, why?

specifically it does not work on Python 3.10.4  Windows embeddable package, link https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.10.4/python-3.10.4-embed-amd64.zip

screenshot:
[image]

- the only way i've found to actually exit it is Ctrl+Z+Enter.. .exit / .quit / Ctrl+D doesn't work either, but Ctrl+Z+Enter actually works.
- notably the windows-embed version (where quit() doesn't work) is only 8.1MB, while the full installer version is 27.1MB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following with the Windows embeddable:

```
import sys
sys.quit()
```

You can read more about this in a more detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19747371/python-exit-commands-why-so-many-and-when-should-each-be-used).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, embeddable python does not recognize `exit()` directly.
You can use the following:

```
import sys
sys.exit()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).