# Terminate all running threads at specific time

Tags: python, multithreading, threadpool, exit, apscheduler

i made a downloader based on a scheduler. So I wanted to download files at starting at a time of and stop before 6 am. I managed to achieve this using apscheduler that starts at 12 am, but i am not sure how to terminate all the task at 6 am. I am doing multi threading as i need to download as many things as possible by 6 am. i tried scheduling a `exit` at 6 am but it doesn't stop the threads and only exits current thread. i want to exit all threads by 6 am. here is the code i tried ::

```
executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 5)
urls = [...] # list of all urls

def download(url):
    ... # downloader here
    
def main_download():
    futures = [executor.submit(download, url) for url in urls]
    for future in as_completed(futures):
        ... # do something
        
scheduler = apscheduler.schedulers.background.BlockingScheduler(timezone="Asia/Kolkata")
job = scheduler.add_job(main_download, trigger="cron", hour=12)
def kill_all(): # kill everything
    job.remove()
    scheduler.remove_all_jobs()
    scheduler.shutdown()
    quit(1)
    # already tried exit, raise keyboard interrupt, sys.exit
scheduler.add_job(kill_all, trigger="cron", hour=6) # kill everything
scheduler.start()
```

But it still continues the download everything, is there a good way to stop all threads? As this exists only current thread and other processes continues to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution might be using `os._exit(n)`. exit, quit, and even sys.exit raises `SystemExit` which only terminates current thread and can be caught by handlers. Where as `os._exit(n)` exits the code without calling cleanup handlers, flushing stdio buffers. So your solution might just be using `os._exit(n)` But be warned it is not a good way to exit and should only be used in special cases. So use it carefully.

The difference between each of them has been explained briefly in the following [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19747562/14344037)

Comment: That works!!! Thanks, is there any downside of using `_exit`?

Comment: Yes, as I said, this is not a good way to exit. From your code i can see, your only work is scheduling and downloading. So this should be fine