# python how to stop the entire code if 1 code doesnt work

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a function that allows reading a file, and if the file we want them to read doesn't exist, I want other functions and other code writing in the code to stop.

```
def readfile():
    ok = False
    while not ok:
        try:
            fnR = input()
            f = open(fnR,"r")
            readcontent = f.read()
            ok = True
        except:
            print("file not found")
            slc = int(input("to exit type '0' \n to try again type '1' "))
            if slc == 0:
                break
            elif slc == 1:
                ok = False

readfile()


x = 15+10
print(x)
```

i dont want to print x or calculate x i want to stop the entire code below the "readfile()" functions

Comment: What do you mean by "code"? The function? The script?

Comment: If you plan on reading a single file, and just stopping if the file doesn't exist, why would you need the while loop? :)

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is exit the script if a file could not be read (you can use `raise SystemExit` - this will exit the script and send the appropriate exit code to the OS.
You can refer to the top answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19747371/python-exit-commands-why-so-many-and-when-should-each-be-used).

Comment: If you are aware of such a detailed and highly voted answer, why did you answer this question instead of flagging as a duplicate?

Comment: @Tomerikoo fair point - it would have been better to put any additional explanations as a comment rather than an answer

Answer (score 0):

To stop a python program, you can use [the exit() function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html?highlight=exit#exit).

```
        if slc == 0:
            exit()
        elif slc == 1:
            ok = False
```

Comment: when i try this code in "except:" its work but it doesnt work when i try this in "try:"

Answer (score 0):

replace `break` with `exit()` - it exits the program instead of exiting the loop