# python does not recognize "quit()"

Tags: python, exit

I've started python in a DOS window. it displays "Python 3.12.0"....
But if I input "quit()", I got the message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'quit' is not defined
```

Now I cannot quit python. Why?

Comment: `quit()` function is not available in the interactive mode you are using in the DOS window. you can use `exit()` or `exit(0)`. these both should exit the python interactive mode and bring back to the DOS prompt

Comment: On my own computer it's no problem to quit python using "quit()" (I encountered problem by erroneously using "quit" without parenthesis). Now the error is on a server. Under windows start menu it display "Python 3.10", but in interactive mode the display is "Python 3.12.0". Therefore I suspect  improper installation/update?

Comment: it's same on server i just checked it. if you say yes, then i can upload both images local and server.

Comment: On the server: I've tried with "py -3.10", the result is the same as with "python"-start (but the display is still "Python 3.12.0 ......", quite strange!?). With "py -3.12", I just got error: "Python 3.12 not found!"

Answer (score 0):

In Python, you can exit the interpreter by typing either `exit()` or pressing Ctrl + Z followed by Enter (on Windows).

Try using `exit()` instead of `quit()` to exit the Python interpreter in the DOS window.

you can use `exit(0)` to exit the Python interpreter as well.

Comment: I've tried, too, with "exit()" and "exit(0)". The result is the same: I cannot quit python.

Comment: If neither exit() nor exit(0) is working to exit Python, you can try by typing  Ctrl + Z and then press Enter. This should exit the Python interpreter in a DOS window on Windows systems. (For unix : Ctrl + D)
If this still doesn’t work, it’s possible that there’s an issue with your Python installation or environment. You may need to close the DOS window manually or use Task Manager to force close it.

Comment: Yes, CTRL+Z, then Enter, this is the only way I can quit python in interactive mode. But why does quit() not work perperly? I still use it on my own computer without any problem.

Comment: @W.Wang Read about the difference between all the exit commands [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19747371/python-exit-commands-why-so-many-and-when-should-each-be-used). `exit` is an alias for `quit`, this answer is misleading.