# Terminating a python text adventure

Tags: python

so I'm writing a little text adventure and have lots of nested if statements. However, there comes times where I want to terminate the program in one of these if statements to give a "GAME OVER". I've tried quit() and exit(), but at best they still output an error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 9, in 0
SystemExit: 0
```

I'm not using any try/except statements, just if statements.
For example:

```
import sys
if True:
    print "Hello guv'na"
    if True:
       print "Good day, Good day"
       sys.exit(0)
if True:
    print "What's all this then?"
```

yields:

```
Hello guv'na
Good day, Good day
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/austin/test.py", line 6, in 0
builtins.SystemExit: 0
```

I just want the program to terminate after "Good day, good day" without a message. is this possible?

Comment: try `import os` and use `os._exit(code)`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: The normal way to force an exit from Python is to `import sys` at the top of your file, then execute `sys.exit(0)` which will exit silently with `0` status, i.e. no error.

Comment: [How to exit from Python without traceback?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187970/how-to-exit-from-python-without-traceback), [Terminating a Python script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/73663/terminating-a-python-script)

Comment: How are you executing your script? Maybe you were not the author of the try/except block, but you are using a framework that does so. Also, the fact that your traceback contains `<string>` is a strong signal that your code is being executed via `exec` (in other words, the code you have shown us is not the whole code that is being executed)

Comment: Side note. If you ever split your code in functions for, say, different sections on the adventure, then you can use return.

Comment: it seems that you launch the script from within a certain editor/idea and that tools adds some wrapper code around the code you actually type. try to run from command line directly and see if it is still reproducible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are seeing that exception, it means that something is catching and printing it.

My guess is that you have a try/except block like this:

```
try:
    do_something()
except:
    print_exc()
```

Here the `except:` clause does not have an exception type specified, which means that **all** kind of exceptions (including `SystemExit`) will be caught.

Bare `except:` clauses are meant for cleanup code and generally re-raise the exception after catching it. Avoid them unless you absolutely need them.

Use this instead:

```
try:
    do_something()
except Exception:
    print_exc()
```

This way, you'll catch only `Exception` subclass, i.e. all standard exceptions except `SystemExit`, `KeyboardInterrupt` and `GeneratorExit`.

Answer (score 0):

The brute force approach (below) should do what you want (well kill the program anyway).

```
import os
os.system('pkill python')
```