# Can I let python do something when manually close the program?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For instance, let the program write down a log file before I manually stop it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to exit from Python without traceback?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187970/how-to-exit-from-python-without-traceback)

Comment: @McGrady I don't think it's a duplicate -- the question you refer to is about exiting without traceback; this one is about having exit hook.

Comment: This question is in a Review Queue. I voted to close as "Unclear what you are asking". I think you can salvage the question by providing more details. If English is a second language, then use Google translator. We can clean up the English.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `atexit` module: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/atexit.html

Example:

```
import atexit
import time

def exit_hook():
    print("Exiting!")

atexit.register(exit_hook)

while True:
    print("looping...")
    time.sleep(1)
```