# Perl to python open() command translation

Tags: python, perl

How do I write open(SCRPT, ">$script") or die...; in python??
Im trying to run a script in python to automate a slurm job. For that, I am trying to create and open a file names SCRPT and write a block of code to be read and executed.

Is it
SCRPT = open(script)
with open(SCRPT)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to exit from Python without traceback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187970/how-to-exit-from-python-without-traceback)

Comment: @MarcusMüller What in the world does that question have to do with this one?

Comment: Tutorial for [open](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/python/open-method) in python.

Comment: @Shawn I'm assuming a perl programmer can look up python docs. So, since `open`'s equivalent is also called `open`, what remains is the `or die...` part

Answer (score 2):

The builtin `open` is typically used to create a filehandle. `open` raises `IOError` if anything goes wrong. The functional equivalent of `open(SCRIPT,">$script") or die $error_message` would be

```
import sys
try:
    script = open("script", "w")
except IOError as ioe:
    print(error_message, file=sys.stderr)
    sys.exit(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

File IO in Python is most commonly done using the `with ... as` operators and the `open` function, like so:

```py
script = '/path/to/some/script.sh'
with open(script, 'w') as file:
    file.write(
        '#!/bin/bash\n'
        'echo hello world\n'
    )
os.chmod(script, 0o755)  # optional
```

Note: You only need to do the `os.chmod` if you need the new script to be directly executed.