# How can I override the keyboard interrupt? (Python)

Tags: python, signals, interrupt

Is there anyway I can make my script execute one of my functions when `Ctrl+c` is hit when the script is running?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205317/capture-keyboardinterrupt-in-python-without-try-except for several options.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Take a look at [signal handlers](http://docs.python.org/library/signal.html#example). CTRL-C corresponds to [SIGINT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGINT_%28POSIX%29) (signal #2 on posix systems).

Example:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python
import signal
import sys
def signal_handler(signal, frame):
    print("You pressed Ctrl+C - or killed me with -2")
    sys.exit(0)
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
print("Press Ctrl+C")
signal.pause()
```

Comment: note: this one should also hit the signal handler when you go `kill -2 [pid]` in the OS

Comment: @wim, good point, thanks, added a hint to my answer - is there actually a way to distinguish a kill by keyboard from a kill by kill?

Comment: I have seen the former will raise a `KeyboardInterrupt` exception in python, the latter won't.  But I'm not sure on the implementation details of why this is so.

Answer (score 9):

Sure.

```
try:
  # Your normal block of code
except KeyboardInterrupt:
  # Your code which is executed when CTRL+C is pressed.
finally:
  # Your code which is always executed.
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the [KeyboardInterrupt exception](http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.KeyboardInterrupt) and call your function in the `except` block.