# Bind a keyboard shortcut to exception in python

Tags: python, exception, keyboardinterrupt

One can send a `KeyboardInterrupt` to a running python program by pressing `Ctrl-c`. Is there a way to bind other keyboard combinations to custom python exceptions?

Specifically, I usually stop my program by pressing `ctrl+c` and then it handles the exception and exits cleanly. However, occasionally I want to stop it such that it performs a different cleanup procedure on exit. My program usually runs for several days without stopping so when I am launching it I do not know which way I want to use to kill it.

In a nutshell, I want to execute different cleanup procedures, based on some user input during runtime. My program is very computationally intensive so I would prefer a solution where I can send an exception rather than poll for user input.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Catching KeyboardInterrupt in Python during program shutdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21120947/catching-keyboardinterrupt-in-python-during-program-shutdown)

Comment: Is this Windows-only, *nix-only, or cross-plaftorm? On *nix, you can use a signal handler—`^C` sends a `SIGINT`, but if you want to send a different signal, you can open another terminal window, or just `^Z` your program into the background, and use the `kill` command to send a different signal instead.'

Comment: Another option is to just run your whole program in a thread, or a child process, and let the main thread/process just wait on input and use that to decide what to do.

Comment: Daniele, my question is different, I added some edits.

Comment: abarnert, I am on unix and the kill command sounds like it might be able to do what I want. However, I am having difficulty finding how I can handle Ctrl+C and `kill` differently.

Comment: Oh, I found it. Yes, this will do the trick, thanks.