# Python - How to stop a function

Tags: python, function, sip

I'm trying to do some sort of Session Initiation Protocol sniffer. I'm using the `pyshark` module for python that offers me some functions to sniff packets from an interface. The thing is that there is a function called `sniff()` that when I give a parameter `packet_count=0` it checks for packets indefinitely until I stop the whole program.

What I want to know if there is a way to stop the `cap.sniff()` function and retrieve the `cap._packets` (which is a list) and then let the rest of the program run.

Here is the code that I made:

```
def sniffsip():
    cap = pyshark.LiveCapture(interface='Ethernet')
    cap.sniff(packet_count=0)#This is function sniff() that checks for packets

    udp_packets = []

    for i in cap._packets:
        j = cap._packets.index(i)
        if cap._packets[j].transport_layer == 'UDP' and cap._packets[j].highest_layer == 'SIP':
            udp_packets.append(cap._packets[j])

    return udp_packets
```

Comment: Where would you like to stop the function? A `break` `return` or `continue` could all do the job but some more context on how this function is working in your script would be helpful.

Comment: You can probably put the call to `sniff()` in a `try` block and [catch `KeyboardInterrupt` (often bound to Ctrl+C)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21120947/354577). Run the code, stop capturing with Ctrl+C, then continue. I haven't tested this though, so just commenting.

Comment: *cap.sniff(packet_count=0)* is where the script start to check for packets, so I want to stop that function so I can get the *cap._packets* list. As I said before, this *cap.sniff()* is in the pyshark module

Comment: @F.Estevez, that's what I think my suggestion will let you do. Please read the linked page.

Comment: @F.Estevez, also, please use _backticks_ (`\``) not underscores or asterisks to mark code.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you just want to break that cycle.

```
stop_flag = False # It is a global variable, you can set it in other functions

def sniffsip():
    global stop_flag # Our global variable...
    cap = pyshark.LiveCapture(interface='Ethernet')
    cap.sniff(packet_count=0)

    udp_packets = []

    for i in cap._packets:
        j = cap._packets.index(i)
        if cap._packets[j].transport_layer == 'UDP' and cap._packets[j].highest_layer == 'SIP':
            udp_packets.append(cap._packets[j])
        if stop_flag: # Here check the state of the flag
           stop_flag = False # Do not forget to set it false if you want to use the function again.
           break # Break the cycle

    return udp_packets
```

Comment: I think the problem is that `cap.sniff(packet_count=5)` doesn't return. It just keeps capturing packets, so the program doesn't progress past that line.

Comment: Actually, *cap.sniff(packet_count=0)* is where the script start to check for packets, so I want to stop that function so I can get the *cap._packets* list. As I said before, this *cap.sniff()* is in the pyshark module