# Python Script not exiting with keyboard Interrupt

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, keyboardinterrupt, imagegrab

I made a simple script to take screenshots and save it to a file every few seconds.
Here is the script :

```
from PIL import ImageGrab as ig
import time
from datetime import datetime

try :
    while (1) :
        tm = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S')
        try :
            im = ig.grab()
            im.save('/home/user/tmp/' + tm + '.png')
            time.sleep(40)
        except :
            pass
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Process interrupted")
    try :
        exit(0)
    except SystemExit:
        os._exit(0)
```

It works perfectly (in Ubuntu 18.04, python3), but the keyboard interrupt does not work. I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21120947/catching-keyboardinterrupt-in-python-during-program-shutdown/21144662) question and added the `except KeyboardInterrupt:` statement. It again takes a screenshot when I press `CTRL+C`. Can someone help with this?

Comment: Where are you running it from?

Comment: @AbhigyanJaiswal Running in Ubuntu 18.04, python3

Comment: Sorry, I meant like terminal, text editor or IDE

Comment: @AbhigyanJaiswal Sorry, from the bash terminal, script stored in text file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move your keyboard interrupt exception handling one up. The keyboard interrupt never reaches your outer try/except block.

You want to escape the `while` loop; exceptions inside the `while` block are handled here:

> ```
> while True:
>     tm = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S')
>     try :
>         im = ig.grab()
>         im.save('/home/user/tmp/' + tm + '.png')
>         time.sleep(40)
>     except :   # catch keyboard interrupts and break from loop
>         pass
> ```

If you break from the loop on keyboard interrupt, you leave the `while` loop and it won't grab again.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code to fix your problem:

```py
from PIL import ImageGrab as ig
import time
from datetime import datetime

while (1):
    tm = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S')
    try:
        im = ig.grab()
        im.save('/home/user/tmp/' + tm + '.png')
        time.sleep(40)
    except KeyboardInterrupt: # Breaking here so the program can end
        break
    except:
        pass

print("Process interrupted")
try:
    exit(0)
except SystemExit:
    os._exit(0)
```