# How to exit selenium chrome driver when exiting python script?

Tags: python, selenium

I am running the flathunter script everyday for 14 hours and it opens a chromedriver instance on each execution

https://github.com/flathunters/flathunter/blob/main/flathunter/abstract_crawler.py#L48-L56

After a while, I have a lot of those processes open[image]

If that is the case, new instaces of webdriver may fail because of "port already in use" error.

Is it possible to run the webdriver in python in such a way, that it closes the webdriver process when the flathunter.py is exiting (either manually or because of failure)?

Comment: `driver.close()`?

Comment: @MSH I the script quits because of failure or manual abortion, how would you execute any code? (the script is an infite loop, it never stops gracefully)

Comment: You should start using `try-catch`s. You  can capture any failure/keyboarinterrupt. see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21144662/2681662

Comment: @MSH I have not written it by myself, its a community project. And they use trycatch, but there are still unhandled errors, also on some errors you want to kill your script, or maybe you restart your machine etc

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap all your Selenium code with `try-except-finally` block. In the `finally` block you can put a `driver.close()` method so that it will close the `driver` process in case of uncaught exception / failure.
The disadvantage of this approach is that this may cause difficulties with catching the failures with reports listeners.

Answer (score 1):

Just before *`flathunter.py`* exists kill all of the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) processes through [`proc.kill()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48003289/7429447) as follows:

```
import os
import psutil

PROCNAME = "chromedriver" # or geckodriver or IEDriverServer
for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    # check whether the process name matches
    if proc.name() == PROCNAME:
        proc.kill()
```

Comment: flathunter script will never exit byits own, its an infinite for loop. It only exits on failure or if human kills the process. So I guess I would need to call this code just before L48 that usually starts the webdriver?