# raise KeyboardInterrupt() KeyboardInterrupt | asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, keyboardinterrupt

An error occurs when disabling the bot with Ctrl+C in VSCode
Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 118, in run
    return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 653, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\Bots\Discord\tbot\main.py", line 46, in main
    await bot.start(config['token'])
  File "C:\Users\Artem\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 746, in start
    await self.connect(reconnect=reconnect)
  File "C:\Users\Artem\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 627, in connect
    await self.ws.poll_event()
  File "C:\Users\Artem\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\discord\gateway.py", line 619, in poll_event
    msg = await self.socket.receive(timeout=self._max_heartbeat_timeout)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Artem\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\aiohttp\client_ws.py", line 229, in receive
    msg = await self._reader.read()
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Artem\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\aiohttp\streams.py", line 657, in read
    return await super().read()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Artem\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\aiohttp\streams.py", line 616, in read
    await self._waiter
asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Bots\Discord\tbot\main.py", line 49, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main())
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 190, in run
    return runner.run(main)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 123, in run
    raise KeyboardInterrupt()
KeyboardInterrupt
```

main.py:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import json
import asyncio
import os

file = open('config.json', 'r')
config = json.load(file)

intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.message_content = True
bot = commands.Bot((config['prefix']), intents=intents, help_command=None)


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await bot.tree.sync()
    await bot.change_presence(status=discord.Status.dnd, activity=discord.Game(name=".help"))
    print('Bot connected')

@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandNotFound):
        embed = discord.Embed(
        description = f'{ctx.author.mention}, сommand not found!', 
        colour = discord.Color.red()
        )
        sent_message = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        await asyncio.sleep(20)
        await sent_message.delete() 

async def load():
    for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
        if filename.endswith('.py'):
            await bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')

async def main():
    await load()
    await bot.start(config['token'])


asyncio.run(main())
```

The bot uses hybrid commands, if you try to replace asyncio.run with bot.run, the slash commands do not work. Is this a bug or is it considered normal? If it is an error, can you help me solve it? Thanks.
P.S. Python v3.11.1, discord.py v2.2.2

Comment: Please use a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help others read your code faster. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is expected - you can either handle it yourself or use `bot.run` to run the bot instead. [`bot.run`](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/discord/client.py#L859-L865) will work as they're catching the error. To emulate it:

```py
try:
    asyncio.run(main())
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Exiting...")
```

Though, the better approach is to use the builtin `bot.run` command. To use that and register your commands; we need to move the loading of them into the [`setup_hook`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.setup_hook) method. We can either subclass `commands.Bot` and override it, or set the function.

To do the latter:

```py
async def my_setup_func()
    for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
        if filename.endswith('.py'):
            await bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')


bot.setup_hook = my_setup_func
bot.run(config["token"])
```

To do the former:

```py
class MyBot(commands.Bot):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    async def setup_hook(self) -> None:
        for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
            if filename.endswith('.py'):
                await bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')

intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.message_content = True
bot = MyBot((config['prefix']), intents=intents, help_command=None)

# rest of your setup code

bot.run(config["token"])
```

Hope that makes some sense. Some of the [examples](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples) make use of the latter technique.

Answer (score -1):

When you use `Ctrl+C` the os sends a signal to your code, if you want, you can handle it by a try-except. By the way, you can ignore it. check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21120947/catching-keyboardinterrupt-in-python-during-program-shutdown).