# Python 3 keyboard interrupt produces interrupted system call

Tags: python, sockets, interrupt

I've developed a small python daemon, which communicates with other programs using basic socket communication. I want the program to shutdown correctly (closing connections etc.) on a KeyboardInterrupt, which works fine using Python 2 but fails using Python 3.

The program uses a seperate thread to handle incoming connections:

```
self.s = socket.socket()
self.s.bind((host, port))
self.s.listen(5)

while self.running:
    c, address = self.s.accept()
    # Launch new thread to handle the connection
```

The following occurs:

```
^CException in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/threading.py", line 901, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "main.py", line 80, in run
    c, address = self.s.accept()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/socket.py", line 135, in accept
    fd, addr = self._accept()
InterruptedError: [Errno 4] Interrupted system call
```

In Python 2 I could just catch the keyboard interrupt using:

```
except KeyboardInterrupt:
```

and handle the shutdown, but there seems to be some complication using a blocking socket in Python 3, the KeyboardInterrupt is never generated. How can I catch a keyboard interrupt and / or get rid of the interrupt error?

Comment: Have you tried this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6990474/how-can-i-override-the-keyboard-interrupt-python