# How can I not stop the program when ctrl+C is pressed?

Tags: python

I am trying to not stop the program when the user press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>.

Now it's like this:

```
(programm running)
...
(user press ctrl+c)
You pressed ctrl+c
breaks
```

What I want is:

```
(programm running)
...
(user press ctrl+c)
You pressed ctrl+c
not breaks
```

How can I do this? Is it impossible?

I tried this code:

```
try:
    while True: 
        userinput = input()
        if userinput == "stop":
            break
except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
    print('You pressed ctrl+c')
```

I tried adding `pass` to `except`, but It doesn't give the expected output.

Comment: Seems like this was answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6990474/how-can-i-override-the-keyboard-interrupt-python

Comment: It does work, it's just that your try-catch is outside of your while loop, so the programme just ends (after your print). If you put the try-catch inside the while it would continue the loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move it inside the loop as I'm guessing you want to continue looping instead of exiting:

```
while True:
    try:
        userinput = input()
        if userinput == "stop":
            break
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        print('You pressed ctrl+c')
        # or just pass to print nothing
```

Comment: Okay, thanks, but is there a way by *not* using try.. except?

Comment: Yes, but you'll find it more complicated rather than less: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205317/capture-keyboardinterrupt-in-python-without-try-except Basically installing an interrupt handler.

Answer (score 1):

you can easily implement the next step within the try & except or set a `pass` after it.

```
while True:
    try:
        userinput = input()
        if userinput == "stop":
            break
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        # or edit it to the next state in the program.
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

CTRL-C actually means send SIGINT signal to the progress, so you can just handle this signal by your own function.

```py
import signal
import sys
def signal_handler(signal, frame):
    print("You pressed Ctrl+C - or killed me with -2")
    # sys.exit(0)
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
print("Press Ctrl+C")
signal.pause()
```