# Stopping a process pygtk

Tags: python, subprocess, pygtk

I am trying to make a simple application to play and stop a midi file using pygtk.

Here's what I have so far :

```
import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk
import subprocess


class Teacher:

    def __init__(self):

        window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
        window.set_size_request(400, 200)
        window.set_title("Music Teacher")
        window.connect("delete_event",
                   lambda w,e: gtk.main_quit())

        table = gtk.Table(4, 4, True)
        window.add(table)

        play = gtk.Button("Play")
        play.connect("clicked", self.clicked_play)
        play.show()

        stop = gtk.Button("Stop")
        stop.show()

        table.attach(play, 0, 1, 0, 1)
        table.attach(stop, 0, 1, 1, 2)

        window.show_all()

    def clicked_play(self, widget):
        subprocess.Popen(["timidity", "~/somefile.mid"])

    def main(self):
        gtk.main()
        return 0


Teacher().main()
```

Is there I can send interrupt from stop and delete_event to kill the process? Should I be using threads?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16410852/keyboard-interrupt-with-with-python-gtk

Comment: The question title talks about "Ctrl +C" but the body says you want the stop button to cancel the play. Which is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can handle getting a `SIGTERM`, a Ctrl+C, or the stop button being pushed like this:

```
import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk
import subprocess
import signal


class Teacher:

    def __init__(self):
        self.proc = None  # Initialize the handle to our subprocess
        window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
        window.set_size_request(400, 200)
        window.set_title("Music Teacher")
        window.connect("delete_event",
                   lambda w,e: gtk.main_quit())

        table = gtk.Table(4, 4, True)
        window.add(table)

        play = gtk.Button("Play")
        play.connect("clicked", self.clicked_play)
        play.show()

        stop = gtk.Button("Stop")
        stop.connect("clicked", self.clicked_stop)
        stop.show()

        table.attach(play, 0, 1, 0, 1)
        table.attach(stop, 0, 1, 1, 2)

        window.show_all()

    def clicked_play(self, widget):
        self.proc = subprocess.Popen(["timidity", "~/somefile.mid"])

    def clicked_stop(self, widget=None):
        if self.proc:
            self.proc.terminate()
            self.proc.wait()

    def handle_sigterm(self, *args):
        self.clicked_stop()
        sys.exit()

    def main(self):
        signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, self.handle_sigterm)
        try:
            gtk.main()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            self.clicked_stop()
            raise
        return 0


Teacher().main()
```

We just save a reference to the `Popen` object we created in `clicked_play`, and then use that handle to send a `SIGTERM` to the process using the `terminate` instance method in `click_stop`. We then call `wait` (which should finish instantly, unless `timidity` doesn't close on `SIGTERM`) to reap the terminated process (so it won't leave a zombie behind).

I also added a `try`/`except` around the call to `gtk.main()` so that `clicked_stop` will be called if you issue a Ctrl+C, and a `SIGTERM` handler that does the same, should that signal be received.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't understand why we used `signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, self.clicked_stop)` wouldn't 'terminate()' kill the process when we call clicked_stop?

Comment: @AdaXu That line actually registers a signal handler for the GUI process, not the subprocess we're launching. It's used so that if someone sends a `SIGTERM` to your GUI process, we can make sure that we terminate `timidity` prior to the GUI script exiting.

Comment: @AdaXu I actually just noticed a bug in the `SIGTERM` handling. Should be fixed now.