# Catch Keyboard Interrupt to stop Python multiprocessing worker from working on queue

Tags: python, multithreading, exception, keyboardinterrupt

From several posts found on stackoverflow i created this code.

**Scenario**

I want to have a multiprocessing.queue on which several worker "listen"

In case of a keyboard interrupt, the main process should no longer put new items in the queue and with the help of the sentinel objects, the worker should gracefully be stopped.

**Problem**

My problem with the current version where i use

```
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_IGN)
```

To ignore the Ctrl + C is that it is also ignored by the main process.

Any Ideas ? 
Do I need to use the multiprocessing worker pool ? Some examples indicate that i might have to. Can I then still use the queue ?

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Process,Queue
import time
import signal
# http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue
# http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process


class Worker(Process):
    def __init__(self, queue,ident):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()
        # Ignore Signals
        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_IGN)
        self.queue= queue
        self.idstr= str(ident)
        print "Ident" + self.idstr

    def run(self):
        print 'Worker started'
        # do some initialization here

        print 'Computing things!'
        for data in iter( self.queue.get, None ):
            print "#" + self.idstr + " : " + str(data)
            time.sleep(5)
            print "#" + self.idstr + "Queue Size: " + str(self.queue.qsize())

        print "Worker Done"

#### Main ####
request_queue = Queue(10)

for i in range(4):
    Worker( request_queue,i ).start()

try:
    for data in range(1000000):
        request_queue.put( data )
        #print "Queue Size: " + str(request_queue.qsize())
        # Sentinel objects to allow clean shutdown: 1 per worker.
    for i in range(4):
        request_queue.put( None ) 

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print "Caught KeyboardInterrupt, terminating workers"
    while  request_queue.empty()==False:
         request_queue.get()
    request_queue.put( None )
```

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205317/capture-keyboardinterrupt-in-python-without-try-except

Comment: hey paco, yes i found it and i was thinking about how to integrate it. so That the queue would stopped be filling and the workers will be stopped. At a first thought i came to the conclusion that i still want to have the exception in the main thread

Answer (score 1):

Based on your solution (which is good), I added an additional layer of protection incase the main code is unresponsive and the user cancels twice:

```
global STOP

import os, signal
def signal_handler(sig, frame):
    global STOP
    if STOP:
        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_IGN)
        os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGTERM)
    STOP = True
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution. Still I don't like that I get the SIGINT 1 time from main and 4 times from the Worker, but maybe I have to live with that.

1. I specified a signal handler for the Interrupt Signal.
2. After Receiving the first Sig INT I ignore more SIG Int signal
3. I switch the stop flag to TRUE
4. I break out the queue insert loop
5. I call stop function which clears the queue and inserts the stop sentinels

   ```
   from multiprocessing import Pool, Process,Queue
   import time
   import signal
   # http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue
   # http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process

   # Stop Flag for loop
   stop = False

   # Define SIGINT
   def signal_handler(sig, frame):
       print 'You pressed Ctrl+C!'
       global stop
       stop = True
       # Ignore more Ctrl+C
       signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_IGN) 

   signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)

   def stopSentinel(request_queue):
       print "CTRL Stop Queue and insert None"

       # Empty Existing Queue
       while  request_queue.empty()==False:
           request_queue.get()

       # Put One None for each Worker
       for i in range(4):
           request_queue.put( None ) 


   class Worker(Process):
       def __init__(self, queue,ident):
           super(Worker, self).__init__()

           self.queue= queue
           self.idstr= str(ident)
           print "Ident" + self.idstr

       def run(self):
           print 'Worker started'
           # do some initialization here

           print 'Computing things!'
           for data in iter( self.queue.get, None ):
               print "#" + self.idstr + " : " + str(data)
               time.sleep(5)
               print "#" + self.idstr + "Queue Size: " + str(self.queue.qsize())

           print "Worker Done"



   #### Main #####
   request_queue = Queue(10)

   for i in range(4):
       Worker( request_queue, i ).start()

   #### Fill Queue with Data ####
   for data in range(1000000):
       request_queue.put( data )
       #print "Queue Size: " + str(request_queue.qsize())
       # Sentinel objects to allow clean shutdown: 1 per worker.

       # Check for Stop
       print "Check Breakout"
       if stop == True:
           print "Stop Break"
           break

   if stop == True:
       stopSentinel(request_queue)
   else:       
       print "Normal Stop" 
       for i in range(4):
           request_queue.put( None )
   ```