# Broken pipe while training Keras model

Tags: python, docker, keras, gnu-screen, broken-pipe

I'm training a few Keras models one after the other on a remote server using userdocker. I connect to the server through ssh and let them run on different Screens.

To speed things up I had the models train on 5 GPUs, so that 5 different models train at the same time.

Most times the models train without any issues: I detach the screen, logout from the server and let them run overnight. Sometimes, however, they stop with a broken pipe message in the middle of training. Below I include the last part of the message as I think it might be the most relevant, but it's very long and repetitive.

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37063297/python-multiprocessing-basemanager-registered-class-lost-connection-immediately) with a slightly similar error message and they they linked to this [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21104997/keyboard-interrupt-with-pythons-multiprocessing), but I fail to see how I can fix it in my case or where I'm making a mistake in my code that might lead to this problem as it doesn't always happen.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem when using Keras or userdocker? How can one prevent it from happening?

**Error Message**

---

> 23/24 [===========================>..] - ETA: 7s - loss: 1.7797 - acc:
>   0.2219 Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/data_utils.py",
>   line 655, in _data_generator_task
>       self.queue.put((True, generator_output))
>   File "", line 2, in put
>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/managers.py",
>   line 759, in _callmethod
>       kind, result = conn.recv() EOFError
>
> Process Process-259: Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in
>   _bootstrap
>       self.run()
>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
>       self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/data_utils.py",
>   line 665, in _data_generator_task
>       self.queue.put((False, e))
>   File "", line 2, in put   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 758, in
>   _callmethod
>       conn.send((self._id, methodname, args, kwds))
>   IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "main.py", line 406, in
>   
>       group_main(sys.argv[1:])
>   File "main.py", line 346, in group_main
>       steps_per_epoch)
>   File "/netscratch/user01/perge/scripts/pycharm_perge/model_trainer.py",
>   line 78, in train_model
>       steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch, epochs=epochs, callbacks=callBacksList)
>   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py",
>   line 91, in wrapper
>       return func(*args, **kwargs)
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/models.py", line 1256,
>   in fit_generator
>       initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py",
>   line 91, in wrapper
>       return func(*args, **kwargs)
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py",
>   line 2195, in fit_generator
>       workers=0)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py",
>   line 91, in wrapper
>       return func(*args, **kwargs)
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py",
>   line 2310, in evaluate_generator
>       generator_output = next(output_generator)
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/data_utils.py",
>   line 751, in get
>       if not self.queue.empty():   File "", line 2, in empty   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 758, in
>   _callmethod
>       conn.send((self._id, methodname, args, kwds))   IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe