# How to catch but defer an exception

Tags: python, exception, python-3.x

I need to catch a `KeyboardInterrupt` exception at any point in a large while loop but defer handling it at those points where I have all the balls in the air.

Specifically, I'm processing a MIDI file consisting of 2 and 3 byte midi events. I need to detect a KeyboardInterrupt at any time but I must never break off processing in the middle of a midi event.

Can someone please suggest the best way of doing this?

Comment: At least tell us which programming language you use.

Comment: Python 3 - sorry, I was thinking I was in a Python forum.

Comment: Is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205317/capture-keyboardinterrupt-in-python-without-try-except what you're looking for?

Comment: Thank you James_pic - best idea yet. But signals can be tricky to use without creating race conditions. If I create a handler for SIGINT which simply flags that ctrl-c has been received then returns, I'm not sure whether that may still have aborted a putbyte. If so, I'll still have the problem of knowing whether the byte made it out of the system or not.

Comment: But can adapt the code there: In the event handler create new custom events that you put in a queue or similar. When you are ready, you process the queue.