# Cleanly Exit on Ctrl+C

Tags: python, locking, signals, code-cleanup, keyboardinterrupt

When an exception occurs, I want to cleanly exit without partially processed data.  This is the sort of code that I'm trying:

```
exit_lock = threading.lock()
def sig_interrupt_handler(signal, frame):
    with exit_lock:
        sys.exit(0)

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, sig_interrupt_handler)

while data_left() > 0:
    with exit_lock:
        data = fetch_data(10)
        for datum in data:
            processor = Processor(datum)
            processor.process()
            datum.delete()
```

However, this code causes my program to lock up when ctrl+c is pressed.  I've tried having the interrupt handler spin off a new thread, but this causes ctrl+c to do nothing.

What is the correct way to ensure a clean exit?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205317/capture-keyboardinterrupt-in-python-without-try-except - This question helped me discover how to use the signal interrupt handler, but, if you need to defer exiting to a certain point in the code, it doesn't help.

Comment: You might have more luck using `catch KeyboardInterrupt` rather than traditional signal handlers.

Comment: That was my first reaction - but when I catch KeyboardInterrupt, I have no way of knowing where my code was when the exception was thrown, and no way to resume it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are facing, is that you are entering a deadlock. In your code, there is only one thread: the main application. It's holding a lock inside the `while` loop, and when you hit `Ctrl+C`, it will deadlock because the interrupt handler is waiting that the lock is released, which will never be released, as the application is locked in the interrupt handler and thus the `while` loop is not being executed.

You'll have more luck with something ressembling

```py
do_process = True

def sig_interrupt_handler(signal, frame):
    global do_process
    do_process = False

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, sig_interrupt_handler)

while data_left() > 0 and do_process:
    data = fetch_data(10)
    for datum in data:
        processor = Processor(datum)
        processor.process()
        datum.delete()
```

You can also have a look at the [signal.alarm(time)](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/signal.html?highlight=alarm#signal.alarm) function to ensure that the application terminates after a maximum time, or have something like

```py
def sig_interrupt_handler(signal, frame):
    global do_process
    if do_process:
        do_process = False
    else:
        sys.exit(-1)
```

So that the user can hit `Ctrl+C` a second time to kill the process without waiting.

Comment: This code would be perfect - if the code that I put in my question was the only code that I was running.  It isn't, so now I would need to add checks for the do_process variable in every other region of my code.

Comment: This is a rough architecture, I can't guess what you don't disclose... The trick to understand is why the code proposed makes a deadlock. Solutions to circumvent this is very specific to your code (global variable to check, task manager, call of a cleanup function, ...). It's up to you.

Comment: That's the problem - it shouldn't be specific to my architecture.  A proper solution would allow me to `ignore KeyboardInterrupt` for 3 lines and then re-raise it, without looking through the thousands of lines of code to understand how my one change will affect everything else.  A good solution is 100% modular.