# python - how to set more than one Timer

Tags: python, multithreading, timer, python-multithreading

I need to set multi-timers in the same script, i have two functions `fun_1()` and `fun_2()` that I want to execute one time by minute.

I want to execute the two timers in the same time and be able to kill them with `keyboardinterrupt`.

What I tried so far is:

```py
import threading 

def timer_1():
    fun_1()
    threading.Timer(60.0, timer_1).start()
def timer_2():
    fun_2()
    threading.Timer(60.0, timer_2).start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    timer_1()
    timer_2()
```

There is two problems with my code:

1. `timer_2` will be executed after one minute of the `timer_1` execution
2. The `keyboardInterrupt`is ignored

Comment: Doesn't look like threading was implemented properly, but having each timer on a separate thread seems like a good approach. For basics of  https://www.toptal.com/python/beginners-guide-to-concurrency-and-parallelism-in-python

Comment: The timer itself is a separated thread, do you think it's a good idea to run separated threads in separated threads ?

Comment: The keyboard interrupt isn't being handled because you didn't register a handler. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205317/capture-keyboardinterrupt-in-python-without-try-except .