# Incorporate KeyboardInterrupt in Python script for API

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, keyboard-events

I have a python script that connects to an Interactive Brokers API and retrieves security contract information as below:

```
from ibapi.client import *
from ibapi.wrapper import *
import time


class TestApp(EClient, EWrapper):
    def __init__(self):
        EClient.__init__(self, self)

    def contractDetails(self, reqId: int, contractDetails: ContractDetails):
        print(f"contract details: {contractDetails}")

    def contractDetailsEnd(self, reqId: int):
        print("End of contractDetails")
        self.disconnect()
        

def main():
    try:            
        app = TestApp()

        app.connect("127.0.0.1", 7496, 1000)

        myContract = Contract()
        # myContract.conId = "503837634"
        myContract.symbol = "/ES"
        myContract.exchange = "CME"
        myContract.secType = "FUT"
        myContract.currency = "USD"
        myContract.localSymbol = 'ESZ3'
        #myContract.primaryExchange = "ISLAND"        

        time.sleep(3)

        app.reqContractDetails(1, myContract)
        app.run()

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Session completed')
        app.disconnect()
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

In cases where I need to break the process (e.g., the program doesn't end naturally because a contract with specified details isn't found), I've set it up using a try/catch and `KeyboardInterrupt` exception.  This doesn't seem to get picked up so killing the process also kills the established connection and I'm forced to log in again manually.

I've considered using the `signal` module but there doesn't seem to be a natural way to apply [code snippets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205317/capture-keyboardinterrupt-in-python-without-try-except) I've found to allow me to close the connection (`app.disconnect()`) before exiting.

For example, I can implement a version of the linked to answer, as below, but there's no way to pass my app instance to be disconnected by the handler before exiting.

```
def handler(sig, frame):
    print('Exception detected...session completed')
    sys.exit(0)

def main():    
    app = TestApp()

    app.connect("127.0.0.1", 7496, 1000)

    myContract = Contract()
    # myContract.conId = "503837634"
    myContract.symbol = '/ES'
    myContract.exchange = 'CME'
    myContract.secType = "FUT"
    myContract.currency = "USD"
    myContract.localSymbol = 'ESZ3'
    #myContract.primaryExchange = "ISLAND"        

    time.sleep(3)

    app.reqContractDetails(1, myContract)
    app.run()   

    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handler)
    signal.pause()

    app.disconnect()
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Can anyone shed some light on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

According to the docs, the EWrapper::error is an error handler that can receive error code of -1 meaning that there's no error, and a positive error code in case of an actual error. I think the idea is that you don't actually terminate your connection with disconnect. Instead, you should:

- create a thread as it's suggested by the docs
- periodically check this error code to see how the request is doing. If it indicates an error (contract not found?) then terminate the thread, but not the whole connection.

I can't really do more without writing up something myself too - which might be a good idea actually.

Ant tell me, what happens if you don't terminate the thing? Does it wait for ever, or timeouts?

Comment: thanks, will take a look.  yeah, it waits forever...haven't waited long enough to see it timeout.