# Invoking function after KeyboardInterrupt

Tags: python

Is is possible to invoke a function in a `KeyboardInterrupt` after pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>?

I have following code:

```
try:
    #other code

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    GPIO.cleanup()

finally:
    print(summary.getSummary())
```

I have also tried putting the `print(summary.getSummary)` before the `GPIO.cleanup()` inside the exception, but the program exits before executing the `print` command.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It should work. Maybe `# other code` is catching KeyboardInterrupt and processing it so the outer block exists without exception or with a different one.

Comment: `# other code` is just some GPIO setup... I've just recognized that the `finally` statement is being executed but I need the `print(summary.getSummary())` executed before the `GPIO.cleanup()`

Comment: @NiklasSico then just move the print-statement between the `except KeyboardInterrupt:` and  `GPIO.cleanup()`.

Comment: @N3wbie I will upload more of the code later... and putting the print-statement between `except KeyboardInterrupt` and `GPIO.cleanup()` didn't do anything on my machine... :/

Comment: Try using a signal handler instead of try/except as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4205386/4583620) suggests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Catching KeyboardInterrupt should work as expected:

```
import time
try:
    while True:
        print("Sleeping")
        time.sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt as ki: 
    print("\nCaught KeyboardInterrupt")
finally:
    print("Finally here")
```

prints:

```
^C
Sleeping
Caught KeyboardInterrupt
Finally here
```

It is possible that the code in the `try` block is catching `KeyboardInterrupt` or `BaseException`, so the outer block cannot catch it.

Also note, from [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#KeyboardInterrupt):

> Catching a KeyboardInterrupt requires special consideration. Because it can be raised at unpredictable points, it may, in some circumstances, leave the running program in an inconsistent state. It is generally best to allow KeyboardInterrupt to end the program as quickly as possible or avoid raising it entirely. (See Note on Signal Handlers and Exceptions.)

Comment: The correct and good answer to his question, but it won't solve his problem!

Comment: @N3wbie the OPs problem cannot be solved without additional information because it is not reproducible and the above is too long for a comment.

Comment: You are right. That is why I upvoted your answer. As you stated, the question is not sufficiently asked to solve his problem.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can, just give you an example:

```
import time

try:
    print("1")
    time.sleep(10)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("2")
finally:
    print("3")
```

then  when you ctrl+C immediately :

```
1
^C
2
3
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).