# How can I terminate a python program from an embedded IPython shell?

Tags: python, ipython

I have the problem that for debugging purposes I drop into an IPython shell in a loop:

```
for x in large_list:
  if x.looks_bad():
    import IPython
    IPython.embed()
```

From there I may want to terminate the *parent* program, because after debugging the problem cause, `embed()` would be called a lot of times.  `sys.exit(1)` is caught by IPython, so I cannot use that.

Comment: This is actually a similar question as [173278](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173278/is-there-a-way-to-prevent-a-systemexit-exception-raised-from-sys-exit-from-bei), just from IPython instead of the unittest module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sys.exit` just raises the `SystemExit` exception.  The following works by hard-killing the program:

```
import os
os._exit(1)
```

To easier find this in my IPython history with `Ctrl-r exit` (the last line will not be saved to the history), I actually wrote this line once, with a deliberate typo:

```
import os; os._exit(1)_
```