# why is pdb on Python 3 ignoring my CTRL+C and just displaying "--KeyboardInterrupt--"

Tags: python-3.x

Under `pdb` in Python 2 I could CTRL-C and quit my Python program.

Under Python 3.6 I doesn't do that, just displays **--KeyboardInterrupt--** and ignores me.  In order to quit, I need to CTRL-D instead, but that will also terminate my bash session if I "do one too many".

Can I bring back CTRL+C behavior?

[image]

Python 3.6, macOS Sierra.

Comment: I'm currently looking into it, and hope I can provide a solution. As a [quick note](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27588/how-can-i-keep-controld-from-disconnecting-my-session), you can set `set -o ignoreeof` in your `.bashrc`, so that Ctrl-D will not exit your bash/ssh session.

Comment: It seems to be working correctly on my end, so I'm on a dead end, sorry. Could you check [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#pdb.Pdb) piece of documentation? I think setting the `nosigint` variable to True could disallow pdb messing with the `SIGINT` handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still consistently have the same behavior.  Maybe it’s a glitch in my environment but otherwise I can’t see the benefit of explicitly ignoring a user’s request to terminate a program with CTRL+C.

However, I have found that hitting ‘**q**’ triggers *pdb quit* which mostly ends up with the desired result, termination of the program. And, unlike CTRL+D has no risk of closing the launching bash session either.

#### edit - this did the trick

(I have code that is made to trap exceptions, which is why a simple q/quit was hit or miss)

as per [Is there a way to prevent a SystemExit exception raised from sys.exit() from being caught?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/173323)

: note its warning about **no cleanup code being run**

```
# ~/.pdbrc
alias qq import os; os._exit(1)
```